# Why searching and displaying search string from files generating error

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to build on example in another question 
[filter directory in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650678/filter-directory-in-python)

and trying to add and return the line found along with filename in which it is found. Here is the code

```
import os

searchdir = r'C:\Python27\mycode'
searchstring = 'import sys'

def found_in_file(fname, searchstring):
    with open(fname) as infp:
        for line in infp:
            if searchstring in line:
                return True, line
        return False

with open('found.txt', 'w') as outfp:
    count = 0
    search_count = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(searchdir):
        for name in files:
            count += 1
            full_name = os.path.join(root, name)
            b_found,line = found_in_file(full_name, searchstring)
            if b_found:
                outfp.write(full_name + '\n')
                outfp.writ(line+'\n')
                search_count += 1

print 'total number of files found %d' % count
print 'number of files with search string %d' % search_count
```

I am receiving error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/mycode/fsearch", line 20, in <module>
    b_found,line = found_in_file(full_name, searchstring)
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

any advise? what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If found_in_file hits this line:

`return False`

a `bool` is returned. But here

`b_found,line = found_in_file(full_name, searchstring)`

You expect for two values to be returned. When found_in_file returns, Python thus iterates the returned value to grab the first two values out of it - but it returned a bool, which CAN'T be iterated, and Python gives up and throws an exception: `TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable` which is exactly what happened - it tried to iterate a bool to unpack two values from it and could not.

Try `return False, None` for example.

Comment: still bit confused. if two values are returned first is boolean and second one is  say a string. like v_bool,v_string=found_in_file (name, saerchstring) then why cant python get and assign values to variable it is just saying that v_bool is false i.e. nothing returned and v_string is empty

Comment: @x0rcist No. When you return from found_in_file like this: `return False` you return exactly one value, a boolean `False`. Python wants to assign one value, a boolean `False`, to two variables, `b_found` and `line`. To assign one value to two values, it must be iterable, so it attempts to iterate it and assign the first value to `b_found` and the second value to `line`, but `bool` is not iterable so it throws an error. You can solve this by `returning False,None` because then Python will see that as many arguments are returned as need to be assigned to variables.