# Delete file if it contains a string

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search for string in txt file Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940032/search-for-string-in-txt-file-python)

How, in python, can I delete a file if it contains a string.
I want it to go though all files in a directory, open them, check if they contain a string, if yes, deletes the file and moves onto the next one.

Comment: How big are the files?  Are they ascii or binary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few pieces to this problem.  First, you need a listing of the files.  Depending on your needs:  `glob.glob`, `os.listdir` or `os.walk` might be appropriate.  You also need to know how to open a file and search for the string.  The easiest (naive) way to do this is to open the file, read all the contents and check if the string is present:

```
def check_file_for_string(filename,string):
    with open(filename) as fin:
         return string in fin.read()
```

This naive way isn't ideal as it will read the entire contents of your file into memory which could be a problem if the files are really big.

Finally, you can use `os.remove` or `os.unlink` to delete the file if `check_file_for_string` returns `True`.