# how to find a string existing in file using mmap

Tags: python

I have a function that take list of urls and save in to file based on a first letter of url.
First, I removed http:// and filter the first letter and join that first letter with file extension and fine that file to search whether the url exists in the file if it exists skip it if not write in the file and append into diff_url_list
Here is source code

```
def checkDiffUrls(url_list):
import mmap
diff_url_list=[]
file_extension="txt"
for urls in url_list:
     temp_url=urls.replace("http://","")
     url_head=temp_url[0][0]
     path=".".join((url_head,file_extension))
     file=open("urls/"+path,'w')
     file_read = mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
     if urls not in file_read:
         file.write(urls)
         diff_url_list.append(urls)
     file.close()

return diff_url_list
```

it gives me an error
 mmap length is greater than file size
Can anybody fix that bug?
Thank you.
I appreciate that.

Comment: you have opened `file` as `"w"`, the file will be truncated, even though in the very next line you associate it with a read-only `mmap`; did you maybe want to use `"w+"` for read/write access to the file?

Comment: also consider using the first letter that is not `w` and not `.`

Comment: even though I change w to w+ it still gives me an an error mmap length is greater than file size

Comment: well all url has http:// front

Comment: You can find answer on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940032/search-for-string-in-txt-file-python

Comment: You can find answer on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940032/search-for-string-in-txt-file-python