# Extract a list of unique visitors from a log file

Tags: python, regex, parsing, search, logging

I would like to extract from a list of log files (named `access.log.*`) that look like this

```
95.11.113.x - [15/Nov/2013:18:25:17 +0100] "GET /files/myfile.rar HTTP/1.1" 200 2437305154 blah.com "http://www.blah.com/files/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0)" "-"
95.11.113.x - [15/Nov/2013:18:25:19 +0100] "GET /files/myfile.rar HTTP/1.1" 200 2437305154 blah.com "http://www.blah.com/files/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0)" "-"
95.11.113.x - [15/Nov/2013:18:25:21 +0100] "GET /files/myfile.rar HTTP/1.1" 200 2437305154 blah.com "http://www.blah.com/files/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0)" "-"
125.111.9.x - [15/Nov/2013:20:00:00 +0100] "GET /files/azeazzae.rar HTTP/1.1" 200 2437305154 blah.com "http://www.blah.com/files/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0)" "-"
132.41.100.x - [16/Nov/2013:11:15:11 +0100] "GET /files/myfile.rar HTTP/1.1" 200 2437305154 blah.com "http://www.blah.com/files/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0)" "-"
132.41.100.x - [16/Nov/2013:11:15:11 +0100] "GET /files/myfile.rar HTTP/1.1" 200 2437305154 blah.com "http://www.blah.com/files/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0)" "-"
132.41.100.x - [16/Nov/2013:11:15:11 +0100] "GET /files/myfile.rar HTTP/1.1" 200 2437305154 blah.com "http://www.blah.com/files/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0)" "-"
```

a list of **unique** visitors (only one repetition per day) who visited `/files/myfile.rar`, i.e. :

```
95.11.113.x - [15/Nov/2013] "GET /files/myfile.rar HTTP/1.1" 200 2437305154 blah.com "http://www.blah.com/files/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0)" "-"
132.41.100.x - [16/Nov/2013] "GET /files/myfile.rar HTTP/1.1" 200 2437305154 blah.com "http://www.blah.com/files/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0)" "-"
```

I tried to open files and look for the desired string `/files/myfile.rar` like this : [Search for string in txt file Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940032/search-for-string-in-txt-file-python), but I didn't achieve to test for "same IP adress" and repetitions.

**What should I use to do this? Standard string search, one line after another ([Search for string in txt file Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940032/search-for-string-in-txt-file-python)) ? Regexp?**

*PS : even better for future use (sorting per date, etc.)* :

```
2013-11-15 - 95.11.113.x - "GET /files/myfile.rar HTTP/1.1"
2013-11-16 - 132.41.100.x - "GET /files/myfile.rar HTTP/1.1"
2013-11-17 ....
```

Comment: use regex to extract the ips into a `set` and you're good. I've done it with groovy/grails but it still may help: https://bitbucket.org/alfasin/log-analyzer and [*this page*](https://bitbucket.org/alfasin/log-analyzer/src/2805691175c1fcc1fda4cc7cf0b151cfe0029f93/grails-app/domain/netflix/Log.groovy) in specific

Comment: yes but I will only have the ips in a `set` and I won't have the dates anymore ? @alfasin

Comment: By the way, is there a way in order to ask Apache to give FULL IP in the logs @alfasin, and not  incomplete IP like `123.123.123.x` ?

Comment: You can parse the date exactly like you can parse the ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here should be the algorithm for your python code:

1) Read each line from the file.
2) If the line contains the text `/files/myfile.rar` then
  3) Parse the IP address from the line. You can use regex, or can use split before space for that.
  4) Save the line into a `dict()` variable in python like this way `visitors[ip] = line`

When you are done, print the `visitors` for output.

Here is the sample code for 3) and 4) as your requested.

```
visitors = dict()
# this should be same for each line
line = '95.11.113.x - [15/Nov/2013]'
ip = line.split(" - ")[0]  # assuming it must have " - " in line
visitors[ip] = line

# finally when you are done with above things
for visitor in visitors:
    print visitors[visitor]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @SabujHassan. Can you give more details for 3) and 4), I'm new to such tools ! (PS : I didn't downvote!)

Comment: Read the file line by line using a loop. Then perform 2,3,4 on each line.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to get your answer sorted by date, that is - unique visitors per day who requested `myfile.rar`, for all files named `access.log.*`:

```
import glob

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(set)

for file in glob.glob('access.log.*'):
   with open(file) as log:
      for line in log:
          if len(line.strip()): # skips empty lines
              bits = line.split('-')
              ip = bits[0].strip()
              date = bits[1].split()[0][1:][:-9]
              url = bits[1].split()[3]
              if url == '/files/myfile.rar':
                  d[date].add(ip)

for date,values in d.iteritems():
  print('Total unique visits for {}: {}'.format(date, len(values))
  for ip in values:
     print(ip)
```

Comment: Thank you! There must be a small mistake because `log` has no  `.split` ? We need to add a loop on each line ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer below is the result of SabujHassan's answer method. I only post it for future use.

```
visitors = dict()

with open('access.log.52') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if '/files/myfile.rar' in line:
            ip = line.split(" - ")[0]  # assuming it must have " - " in line
            visitors[ip] = line

for ip in visitors:
    print visitors[ip]
```