# How to read text file line by line and do something for a particular line?

Tags: python

I want to read a text file line by line. I found how to read line by line by searching but not how to call a specific line in a text file. Basically, i want to do something with particular lines( like the first line, the second line, the third line, etc):

```
if particular_line is something:
....
```

Also, how can i do something like this:

```
if return_from_another_function in file:
....
```

Basically, i want an example of how i could do that if it's possible.

Comment: did my solution worked for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f = open('filename', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
```

now you get a list type object `lines` which you can use to access particular line or  iterate and search for particular line.

Answer (score 1):

The standard [linecache](http://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html) module makes this a snap:

```
import linecache
theline = linecache.getline(thefilepath, desired_line_number)
```

For your second que ([from Ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940032/search-for-string-in-txt-file-python?answertab=votes#tab-top)):

If your file is not too large, you can read it into a string, and just use that (easier and often faster than reading and checking line per line):

```
if 'blabla' in open('example.txt').read():
    print "true"
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably this will help:

```
myfile = open(filename, "rb", 0)
for line in myfile
   if(line is "your string to be compared")
       print "do something here"
```