# How to read a specific word from a txt file and print the content following it using Python?

Tags: file, python-2.7, text

I want to read a .txt file in python and then find a specific word in it and print content up to certain length .

I tried reading using

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
f.read()
f.find("xx")
```

// this returns value -1

suppose my file is like this

```
'naba:12:naba, xyz:13:xyz, xxx:23:cww'
```

and I want to read and Print the content between two naba:

Comment: Have you checked this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940032/search-for-string-in-txt-file-python)?

Comment: You are reading from the file and not storing it in a string buffer. Read from a file, store in a string and then call string method find()