# Check if a string is in a file with Python

Tags: python, file, if-statement

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to figure out how I can search for a string in a file and use it as a condition in a if clause: 
If "String" is in the file, Print("Blablabla")

Answer (score 55, accepted):

As you yourself said, just open the file and check if it is in it.

```
with open('myfile.txt') as myfile:
     if 'String' in myfile.read():
         print('Blahblah')
```

Isn't `Python` delightful?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, we can use "open('myfile.txt', 'r')" in order to only reading the file, and avoiding the ".read()" ahead.

Comment: Is it possible to ignore case?

Comment: @Ferdossi just do 'String'.lower() in myfile.read().lower()

Answer (score 8):

This is the top answer from a [very similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940032/search-for-string-in-txt-file-python)

```
if 'blabla' in open('example.txt').read():
    print "true"
```

Comment: Won't this leave the file stream open?

Comment: This method didn't work for me :(

Comment: @SrgSprinkles I'm guessing it didn't work because this answer is Python 2 where the first answer is Python 3.  You have to call the right binary.  print"" and print() are not interchangeable between versions