# how to output a tring from an nfc tag to a text file using arduino uno and pn532?

Tags: arduino, tags, nfc, rfid, spi

iam in a deep trouble , I have an Arduino uno and a pn532 connected to it in SPI mode , I want to read a string from an nfc tag and output it to a text file , I have already managed to read from nfc tag and write on it easily , but what Iam facing now is how to output the string contained in the nfc tag to a text file instead of outputting it to the serial monitor of the Arduino studio , any help would be greatly appreciated , thanks a lot in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write the file from the Arduino itself, you have a few options, depending on the available extra hardware and where you want to save the file.

The easier is to use a SD card and the standard [SD Library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/SD). On the official reference page there are lots of examples.

If you want to save it on the PC, there are several virtual terminal applications that enables you to save the sent and received data. [Coolterm](http://freeware.the-meiers.org/) is one of them, Putty is another one.

You can also make your own application that receives the data from the arduino through serial communication, and handle the file saving on this application.

Comment: My dear iam very thankful to you , both coolterm and hyperterminal worked great for me , I don't know to thank you ,,, now do you have any idea about a java program to read a string from that text file and search for it in another text file ? any guide would be greatly appreciated , thanks in advance .

Comment: I don't know much about java, but i've done similar things using python. Maybe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940032/search-for-string-in-txt-file-python) can help you.