# How to use a "for loop" to search for a correct password out of a big list of potential passwords

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I recently participated in a capture the flag event in a beginners cyber security class. One of the challenges was to write a "for loop" to check for the correct password out of a big list (over 1000). How would I accomplish this quickly? Or is a "for loop" even the best way to do it?
(I have a txt file containing all possible passwords)

Comment: Is the list sorted? Are you only checking for a password once, or are you checking multiple passwords against it one after another?

Comment: You mention that the list is txt file, so this might be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/q/3277503/562359

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To get good answers, you should include any code you've tried in your question and more details about the problem. It's also recommended to search for other questions that cover the same information. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009882/how-to-read-a-large-file-line-by-line, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205923/checking-if-word-exists-in-a-text-file-python

Answer (score 1):

```py
myGuessedPassword = "PythonIsGr8"

with open("my_password_file.txt", "r") as f:
    my_password_list = f.readlines()
    for passwd in my_password_list:
       if passwd == myGuessedPassword:
         print(passwd)
    else:
       print("The password was not in the file")
```

Comment: Should probably use a variable name that isn't `pass` since that's a keyword...

Comment: this whole thing can be reduced to `myGuessedPassword in my_password_list` (and you probably need `read().splitlines()` or you will get the '\n' characters)

Comment: Oh yeah thanks.

Answer (score -1):

With python, you can simply read the the file into a list assuming they are in a text file.

Sudo code -

pwList = reader(file)

for word in pwList:

if word == “password”

print (“Found password - “,word)

Or you can check to see if word is in list.

if password in pwList:

print(“Password exists in list”)

Comment: Please read the edit help re block & inline code format, also re line breaks, etc. Please before publishing look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box.