# Verify if value is in external text file. If True print value in another file

Tags: python, file

Let's say I had a file called random.txt containing:

```
Youtube
Google
Amazon
Facebook
```

In my Python file I have a variable with a value:

```
var = "Google"
```

What code would be needed to verify if var is in the random.txt. And print True in a new file called true.txt?

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to read from a file?

Comment: Your question is already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205923/checking-if-word-exists-in-a-text-file-python.
Google how to write to a file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.