# Scanning a text file for a word

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am relatively new to python and was working on a project to enhance my skills, it was a text file compressor; 
I am having problems with the file scanning portion, I want it to read a text file and find a word. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

My code:

```
def check(): 
    datafile = file("res\powerserv 1.txt") 
    for line in datafile: 
        if storage in line: 
            return true 
        else: 
            return false
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search for string in txt file Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940032/search-for-string-in-txt-file-python)

Comment: I tried that code already it didn't work

Comment: If it didn't work that's because you didn't try it properly. Please post your file and code here indicating what you tried and why it did not work, along with any tracebacks.

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Why didn't it work? Did it display the wrong data? Did the program crash?

Comment: `def check():
    datafile = file("res\powerserv 1.txt")

    for line in datafile:
        if storage in line:
            return true
        else:
            return false`

Comment: Yes I think you are correct my code had careless mistakes such as lower case t in True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with your code is the `return False` inside the for loop.

Assuming this is your file:

```
word1
word2
word3
```

You are looking for `word3`. Now, this is what your program does:

```
word3 == word1 ? 
No, so break
```

What you need is:

```
word3 == word1 ?
No, next iteration

word3 == word2 ?
No, next iteration

word3 == word3 ?
return True
```

This is how your code should be:

```
def check(word): 
    with open("res\powerserv 1.txt") as datafile: 
        for line in datafile: 
            if word in line: 
                return True 

    return False

print(check('your word'))
```

The `return False` comes outside the loop. Also, consider the use of the `with...as` context manager to handle opening and closing of your files.

Comment: it returns false every time

Comment: @user8480074 Take a look now, I've modified your code.

Comment: @user8480074 If it still doesn't work, your file path is probably the issue. Try: `"res\\powerserv 1.txt"`

Comment: Thank you guys so much it worked, I will post my finished code when I'm done. Thank you agin