# How do I find the position of a word in a .txt file in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a .txt filled with 4000 different words that are listed vertically.
I'm supposed to find the position of a certain word that I input, but I get really weird values for the position for the word's that do exist in the file. This is what my code looks like so far
[image]

So, the very first word on the list is 'the', so if I were to input into the search_word input 'the', I would get a zero when I'm supposed to get 1. Another example, is if I input 'be', I'd get 4 when it's supposed to be ranked at 2.

I think the problem is that my code is only scanning each character in the list instead of scanning each word separately. I have no clue how to fix this!

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't
be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your
question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four
spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: `contents = list(file)` should solve your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search for a string in text files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940032/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-text-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` to generate ranking numbers instead, and the `for-else` construct to output the word and `break` the loop as soon as the word is found, or wait until the loop finishes without breaking to decide that there is no matching word found:

```
with lexicon_file as file:
    for i, w in enumerate(file, 1):
        if search_word == w.rstrip():
            print("Accoding to our Lexicon, '%s' is ranked number %d in the most common word in contemporary American English" % (search_word, i))
            break
    else:
        print("According to our Lexicon, '%s' is NOT in the 4000 most common words of contemporary American English")
```