# Check if pyomo model and generated LP file format is valid and catch error/exception

Tags: linear-programming, pyomo

I have a pyomo `ConcreteModel()` which I solve repeatedly within another stochastic optimization process whereas one or more parameters are changed on the model.

The basic process can be described as follows:

```
# model is created as a pyomo.ConcreteModel()
for i in range(0, 10):    
    # change some parameter on the model
    opt = SolverFactory('gurobi', solver_io='lp')
    # how can I check here if the changed model/lp-file is valid?
    results = opt.solve(model)
```

Now I get an error for some cases where the model and [LP file (see gist)](https://gist.github.com/ckaldemeyer/b6122416c8759e086f913177d004f48e) seems to contain NaN values:

```
ERROR: Solver (gurobi) returned non-zero return code (1)
ERROR: Solver log: Academic license - for non-commercial use only Error
    reading LP format file /tmp/tmp8agg07az.pyomo.lp at line 1453 Unrecognized
    constraint RHS or sense Neighboring tokens: " <= nan c_u_x1371_: +1 x434
    <= nan "

    Unable to read file Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module> File
      "/home/cord/.anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
      packages/pyomo/solvers/plugins/solvers/GUROBI_RUN.py", line 61, in
      gurobi_run
        model = read(model_file)
      File "gurobi.pxi", line 2652, in gurobipy.read
      (../../src/python/gurobipy.c:127968) File "gurobi.pxi", line 72, in
      gurobipy.gurobi.read (../../src/python/gurobipy.c:125753)
    gurobipy.GurobiError: Unable to read model Freed default Gurobi
    environment
```

Of course, the first idea would be to prevent setting these NaN-values. But I don't know why they occur anyhow and want to figure out when the model breaks due to a wrong structure caused by NaNs.

I know that I can catch the solver status and termination criterion from the `SolverFactory()` object. But the error obviously occurs somewhere before the solving process due to the invalid changed values.

How can I can catch these kinds of errors for different solvers before solving i. e. check if the model/lp-file is valid before applying a solver? Is there some method e.g. `check_model()` which delivers `True` or `False` if the model is (not) valid or something similar?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it is better to catch the error at the source as you point out. Pyomo seems to have a [BuildCheck](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/working_abstractmodels/BuildAction.html) method for this. Another way is to open the file and search for `nan` (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940032/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-text-files)), but this will be very slow for large models. I think the best option is to understand why `nan`s occur (e.g., division by zero?) and prevent them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the error is taking place when the parameter values are being changed, then you could test to see whether the sum of all relevant parameter values is a valid number. After all, `NaN + 3 = NaN`.

Since you are getting `NaN`, I am going to guess that you are importing parameter values using Pandas from an Excel spreadsheet? There is a way to convert all the `NaN`s to a default number.

Code example for parameter check:

```
>>> from pyomo.environ import *
>>> m = ConcreteModel()
>>> m.p1 = Param(initialize=1)
>>> m.p2 = Param(initialize=2)
>>> for p in m.component_data_objects(ctype=Param):
...     print(p.name)
... 
p1
p2
>>> import numpy
>>> m.p3 = Param(initialize=numpy.nan)
>>> import math
>>> math.isnan(value(sum(m.component_data_objects(ctype=Param))))
True
```

Indexed, Mutable Parameters:

```
>>> from pyomo.environ import *
>>> m = ConcreteModel()
>>> m.i = RangeSet(2)
>>> m.p = Param(m.i, initialize={1: 1, 2:2}, mutable=True)
>>> import math
>>> import numpy
>>> math.isnan(value(sum(m.component_data_objects(ctype=Param))))
False
>>> m.p[1] = numpy.nan
>>> math.isnan(value(sum(m.component_data_objects(ctype=Param))))
True
```

Comment: I am looking for some generic solution because my pyomo models differ in their structure. Nevertheless, thanks for your answer!

Comment: I edited the answer to add a code check for whether any of the `Param` values attached to the model are `NaN`. This won't work if you directly inject a `NaN` into a constraint expression, though.

Comment: I am working with mutable Params which I change on the model subsequently. Your approach works for scalar Parameters using math.isnan (https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isnan). But does it also hold for arbitrary model structures e.g. when the parameters have a 2-dimensional index, ...? Can it be extented e.g. by using any() so that it is capable of checking all model structures? Anyway, I like the idea of extracting all data and checking if I know the model structure..

Comment: But don't you agree that it would be nice to have something like this included within pyomo?

Comment: @CordKaldemeyer You can certainly use `any` instead of `sum`. I would consider that an improvement. This code works for arbitrary model structures. I agree--it would be nice to have an organized set of tools like this within Pyomo. Pull requests are welcome. I can claim responsibility for some of the (undocumented) code in pyomo.util: https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/tree/master/pyomo/util.

Comment: Thanks for your help. As the answer is generic or can be adapted so, I have accepted. Unfortunately, I do not have time to provide a PR at the moment. But I think the developers a now aware and maybe someone else will push a PR based on your code into the code base. Thanks a lot!