# Search recursively for specific string in a dir full of files

Tags: python, string, file, file-search

I have a huge dir, with sub dirs and txt files. 
I would like to search my dir/s recursevly for a specific string. 
I would like to print the full path, and keyword if i find a match. For some reason I can't seem to get `if keyword in line` to work. (I know that "williams" is in my files)

```
import os
search_path = "/home/lasse/Desktop/DB1"
file_type = ".txt"
keyword = "williams"

if not (search_path.endswith("/") or search_path.endswith("\\")):
    search_path = search_path + "/"

if not os.path.exists(search_path):
    search_path = "." 
    print("Path dosn't exists") 

for folder, dirs, files in os.walk(search_path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(file_type):
            fullpath = os.path.join(folder, file)

            with open(fullpath, 'r') as my_file:
                for line in my_file:
                    print("test")
                    if keyword in line:
                        print(fullpath, line, keyword)
                    else:
                    print("Cant find keyword keyword")
```

Comment: Have you tried to `print(fullpath)` to ensure you're actually getting to the file you know has the keyword in it? And are you sure "williams" is the right keyword instead of "Williams"? Also, check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/4944929/1451664

Comment: i can print the line where it says print("test").. my code never enters the if statement - just skips to the else... also i need the search to be recursive for all files in dirs and sub dirs.. most exampels are only searching one file..

Comment: That `print` will execute for *every* line of *every* file. First indent the print statement under the `else`. Also, create a test with a single file you know contains the keyword to help isolate the problem. Right now it could be that you never actually enumerate a path that contains the keyword or there's a mistake in the keyword itself (lowercase vs uppercase, unicode characters, etc.).

Comment: Thx chris.. i got it under control now :)