# How to perform text search in a Google-docs document using Python3

Tags: python-3.x, google-docs-api

I want to search for key words in my book I am writing with Google docs. I want key worrds to be presented in a list by the page number to see where and how many times a certain word occur.

I havent tried anything. This is my first test at using Stack overflow and my first problem solving using Python.

Is this something I can use for Google docs?
[How to search for a string in text files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940032/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-text-files)

Answer (score 0):

I found the function is built into Docs already (cmd-shift-H).