# writing code that searches for a sync pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

I have a large specific binary file of data that I need to scan for a packet sync pattern 0xEB25. how do I search the file for that specified pattern in python?

Comment: It depends on what type of file your trying to scan. If your trying to scan a text file try going to this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-writing-text-files-python/. It would be easier if you also provided some code.

Answer (score 0):

If it's contained in a text file and that is Hex code, then this should work:

```
def isInFile(string):
    with open('example.txt') as f:
    if string in f.read():
        print("true")
```

then just run

```
isInFile("1110101100100101")
```

Where 1110101100100101 is the hex you gave converted into binary

- See this answer for more specifics:
  [How to search for a string in text files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940032/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-text-files)