# Comparing a Text file to a input

Tags: python, ip

I'm trying to make a basic program to check if a link is a grabify link by comparing it to available grabify domains, I have a text file that contains all the possible domains and I want to check if a user input is the same.

```
Q1 = input("input your website domain: ")
PGD = open('Domains', 'r')

if PGD == Q1:
    print("True")
```

if i input the EXACT domain as one of the lines in my text file it doesn't return anything.

Comment: You must include a sample input and sample output so others can help you effectively

Comment: @PrathameshJadhav Is that good?

Comment: Yes it helps us to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`open()` returns a file instance, so you can't compare it directly to a string ; You need to read the file first. You can use the `in` keyword to search if the string exists in an other string.

Don't forget to close the file at the end.

```py
Q1 = input("input your website domain: ")
PGD = open('Domains', 'r')

if Q1 in PGD.read():
    print("True")

PGD.close()
```

See also : [How to search for a string in text files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940032/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-text-files)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to read the file first, extract the string and remove any newlines that might be there.
Also try to use `with open` to not have to worry about closing the file again

```
Q1 = input("input your website domain: ")

with open('Domains') as fopen:
    
    if fopen.read().strip() == Q1:
        print("True")
```

This assumes you've only got one line in the file. If you had multiple lines to check against:

```
Q1 = input("input your website domain: ")

with open('Domains') as fopen:
    for line in fopen.readlines():
        if line.strip() == Q1:
        print("True")
```