# Check if a user id is in a list of user ids to allow command access - discord.py

Tags: discord.py

im fairly new to python and have been writing a discord bot for a server with me and a few friends as practice. I've added a few commands that could be pretty disruptive if all users had access to them at all times and have been trying to add a method to enable and disable access to them without using discord roles but a python list instead. I added a command that i can use to to add their user id to a list, but when the user tries to use the command they receive a permission error.

the code below is the problematic code from a cog

```
modlist = []

    def ListCheck():
        async def IsInList(ctx):
            member = ctx.message.author.id
            return member in modlist
        return commands.check(IsInList)

    @commands.command()
    async def AddUser(self, ctx, *, question):
        modlist.append(question)

    @commands.command()
    async def ViewModList(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('User ids that have access:')
        for i in range(0, len(modlist)):
            await ctx.send(modlist[i])

    @commands.command()
    async def ClearModList(self, ctx):
        modlist.clear()
        await ctx.send('Modlist cleared')

    @commands.command()
    @ListCheck()
    async def PermTest(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('user is in modlist')
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you could do it would be to use [`commands.check()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20check#discord.ext.commands.Bot.check). The function in the code below checks if the message author, `ctx.author`, is in the given list, `modList`. If the author is in this list when the command 'test' is invoked, then the bot will send "You are a mod!", otherwise it will raise a check error.

```py
modList = [394506589350002688, 697725862128386048] # just some ids as examples

def check_Mod(ctx):
    if ctx.author.id in modList:
        return ctx.author.id in modList

@commands.command()
@commands.check(check_Mod)
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("You are a mod!")
```

The above working is shown in the image below:

[image: Working mod check command]

---

To answer `is there is a way to add user ids to the list via a command?`, you may either use a json or text file. In this case, I will use a text file since it's simpler, and also because my json isn't as fluent as others.

Here's an example of how your text file may look like:

```
394506589350002688
697725862128386048
```

First you need to read the file and check whether the author's id is in the file. We will be changing the `check_Mod` function for this. If you want to know more about reading through a text file, or feel that you may need a more efficient way, you may have a look at this: [How to search for a string in text files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940032/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-text-files)

```py
def check_Mod(ctx):
    with open('Mod.txt') as f: # do change the 'Mod.txt' to the name that suits you. Ensure that this file is in the same directory as your code!
        if str(ctx.author.id) in f.read(): # this is reading the text file and checking if there's a matching string
            return ctx.author.id
```

Now for writing the author id into your text file.

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.check(check_Mod)
async def add_Mod(ctx, user:discord.Member=None):
    if user == None:
        await ctx.send("Please provide a user to add as a Mod!")
        return

    # First we'll make some functions for cleaner, more readable code #

    def is_Mod(user_id): 
    ## This function will check if the given id is already in the file. True if in file, False if not ##
        with open('Mod.txt', 'r') as f:
            if str(user_id) in f.read():
                return True
            else:
                return False

    def add_Mod(user_id):
    ## This function will add the given user id into the given text file, Mod.txt ##
        with open('Mod.txt', 'a') as f: # 'a' is used for appending, since we don't want to overwrite all the ids already in the file
            f.write(f"{str(user_id)}\n")
            f.close()

    # Now we put those functions to use #
    if is_Mod(user.id) == True:
        await ctx.send(f"The user {user} is already a Mod!")
    else:
        add_Mod(user.id)
        await ctx.send(f"{user} added as a Mod!")
```

The above should work as seen in the image below.

[image: Working add_mod command]

p.s. If you have any other questions, please post them as a new question, thank you!

Comment: Your solution above works perfectly so long as the user id is added to the list before the bot is deployed but do you know if there is a way to add user ids to the list via a command? I still get the same error message after adding a user id using my command in the above code

Comment: You could use a json or text file, which would write the user into the file and save the id, since adding to a list will only store the data until the bot is restarted. Then you can parse through it to check if the author's id is in the text file. I can write how to do this in my answer.

Comment: Edited my question to include the add_Mod command as well as checking a text file if the author is a Mod or not. If you have any other questions, please create a new question, thanks!

Comment: awesome ill give it a go, thank you so much for your help