# Python recursion to print items from a list backwards

Tags: python, list, recursion

Using Python, I'm trying to read a list or strings backwards.  When finding the item of interest, I want to print all of those items from that point to the end of the list.  I can do this without recursion and it works fine, but I feel like there's a nicer way to do this with recursion.  :)

Example without recursion:

```
items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5']

items_of_interest = []
items.reverse()
for item in items:
    items_of_interest.append(item)
    if item == 'item3':
        break
    else:
        continue

items_of_interest.reverse()
print items_of_interest
['item3', 'item4', 'item5']
```

**Update:**

To add clarity to the question, the list is actually the output of a grep of a set of strings from a log file.  The set of strings may be repeating and I only want the last set.

Comment: You should just use the example without recursion! Adding recursion will just make Python less efficient and the code harder to read. :)

Comment: This question is based on a faulty idea of what represents good coding style, but otherwise it's a perfectly fine question. I don't think it really deserves to be a +1, but certainly doesn't deserve to be at -1.

Comment: I simplified the question, so I think somebody may have voted it down since they thought it was homework.

Comment: Y U WANT RECURSION IN PYTHON?

Comment: @Omnifarious — unexplained demands for recursive solutions *typically* indicate a homework problem. :)

Comment: @Brandon - Lol about the homework comment.  I forget many students are on here trying to get free answers.  :)

Comment: Could you explain _why_ you thought recursion would be a good fit for this? The recursive versions I can think of are still just reverse iteration disguised. I think that `reversed` rather than `reverse` is the piece to solve the problem, not recursion -- it gives you O(k) performance (where k is the length of the part of the list you want) instead of O(n) performance (where n is the length of the list).

Comment: @agt - Reversed was what I was looking.  I should remember that often times recursion is no longer the right solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recursion wouldn't make this simpler, it would make it more complicated.

```
for i, item in enumerate(reversed(items), 1):
    if item == 'item3':
        items_of_interest = items[-i:]
        break
else:
    # 'item3' wasn't found
```

seems to be the simplest efficient way to do this to me. You only have to iterate over the list from the end to `'item3'`, since `reversed` returns an iterator.

**Edit:** if you don't mind iterating over the whole list to create a reversed version, you can use:

```
i = list(reversed(items)).index('item3')
items_of_interest = items[-i-1:]
```

which is even simpler. It raises an error if `'item3'` isn't in the list. I'm using `list(reversed())` instead of `[:]` then `reverse()` because it's one iteration over the list instead of two.

**Edit 2:** Based on your comment to the other answer, my first version does what you want -- searches for the item from the end without iterating over the whole list. The version in the question has to iterate the list to reverse it, as does my second version.

A minimally modified, but more efficient, version of your original would be:

```
items_of_interest = []
for item in reversed(items):
    items_of_interest.append(item)
    if item == 'item3':
        break
items_of_interest.reverse()
```

Answer (score 1):

A recursive solution is not called for here.  To the problem of finding the slice of a list from the **last** occurrence of a item to the end of the list, one approach is to define an auxiliary function

```
>>> def rindex(s, x):
...     for i, y in enumerate(reversed(s)):
...         if x == y:
...             return -i-1
...     raise ValueError
... 
>>> items[rindex(items, "b"):]
['b', 'f']
```

The auxiliary function can be called `rindex` because Python has a `rindex` method to find the last occurrence of a substring in a string.

If you *must* do it recursively (perhaps it is homework) then think about it as in this pseudocode (not yet worked out completely)

```
def tail_from(list, x):
    return tail_from_aux(list, x, [])

def tail_from_aux(list, element, accumulated):
    if list is empty:
        return []
    elif list ends with element
        return element::accumulated
    else:
        last = list[-1]
        return tail_from_aux(list[:-1], element, last::accumulated)
```

But, this is memory-intensive, goes through the whole list (inefficient), and is not Pythonic.  It may be appropriate for other languages, but not Python.  Do not use.

Since your actual question refers to files, and log files at that, you may not be able to reduce this problem to an array search.  Therefore, check out
[Read a file in reverse order using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301789/read-a-file-in-reverse-order-using-python), there are some interesting answers there as well as some links to follow.

Consider mixing `tac` with `awk` and `grep` if you are able to as well.

Comment: If your list is very long, and you know the item is near the end, then this requires iterating over almost the whole list. The version in the question requires even more iterating, because it uses `items.reverse()` twice plus a reverse iteration, but finding the item can be done without iterating over the whole list using `reversed` which returns an iterator.

Comment: that gives the wrong answer if there's more than one `item3` in the list.

Comment: Oh, oh, nice.  Duh!  I will need to fix the answer.  Too bad there is no `rindex` on lists.

Comment: I'm actually reading the contents of a log file backwards that have been read into a list.  The file can be long and I know what I'm looking for is towards the end, so there's value in reading it backwards.  I simplified the questions to make it easier to discuss.

Comment: Thanks, that does add clarity.  If the log is in a file, though, it seems you would want to attack the problem a little differently.  I will work on a solution.

Comment: @user16738 - You know, your actual problem is far, far more interesting than the toy problem you gave as an example. *grin*