# Print in Reverse Order Python

Tags: python, csv

```
f = urlopen ('http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&d=4&e=29&f=2014&g=d&a=8&b=22&c=1981&ignore=.csv')
sys.stdout = open('output.csv', 'w')
p = f.read()
print p
f.close
```

This successfully opens (or creates) a file called output.csv and outputs the lines from the downloaded file into this local csv. How would I reverse the order that the lines are printed in?

Comment: why am I getting downvoted. Is there a problem with my question?

Comment: @Apollo no, this is just a duplicate of so many questions that it's painful.

Comment: A search of "print lines in file in reverse order python" turns this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2301792/2297365) up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a header in the input, you might want to print the header first; followed by 
the remaining lines.

```
f = urlopen ('http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&d=4&e=29&f=2014&g=d&a=8&b=22&c=1981&ignore=.csv')
with open('output.csv', 'w') as out:
    # print header first
    out.write(f.readline())

    # then print reversed lines
    for line in reversed(f.readlines()):
        out.write(line)

f.close()  # !!!
```

Comment: Argument to `reversed` should be a sequence.

Comment: indeed, forgot that (bleh).

Comment: N.B. this will print the header first and last :)

Comment: `TooManyErrorsError` :D

Comment: @AdamSmith nope, it won't (at least not in this version)

Comment: You don't need to close `out`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala does `readline` actually move the seek? I assumed it did not but I could be wrong :). I would do `f_data = f.readlines(); for line in [f_data[0]] + list(reversed(f_data[1:])): out.write(line)` but that's WAY uglier than yours if that works :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala this is actually something I was struggling to do. Thanks

Comment: @HuuNguyen yeah, had that close dangling there, removed. too bad urlopen does not return something with context mgr in py2.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `readlines()` method to get a list of lines instead of the single string you get from `read()`.  This list can be reversed using the `reversed()` built-in:

```
for line in reversed(f.readlines()):
    print line
```

Comment: I think you meant `print line`.