# Python - How to read previous lines while reading csv file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, row, readline

I want to read rows in excel table but when I want, during reading process, I would like to stop reading forward and I want to read previous lines (backward reading)? How can I go previous rows again?

```
import csv

file = open('ff.csv2', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(file)

for row in reader:
    print row
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301789/read-a-file-in-reverse-order-using-python

Answer (score 1):

You could always store the lines in a list and then access each line using the index.

```py
import csv
file = open('ff.csv2', 'r')

def somereason(line):
    # some logic to decide if stop reading by returning True
    return False  # keep on reading

for row in csv.reader(file):
    if somereason(line):
        break

    lines.append(line)

# visit the stored lines in reverse
for row in reversed(lines):
   print(row)
```