# Python - Getting the average of n lines in a txt file

Tags: python, file, text, numbers, average

I've taken a look online to try and solve this problem and used solutions from other posts to build towards my solution, however from here, I don't get what to do next.

I basically want to grab the final 5 lines of the PastWinners text file and then get the average of those numbers. What I currently have gets the average of the entire document and also prints out the final line in the text file.

```
with open('PastWinners.txt') as f:
    data = [float(line.rstrip()) for line in f]

    first = f.readline()      # Read the first line.
    f.seek(-2, 2)             # Jump to the second last byte.
    while f.read(1) != b"\n": # Until EOL is found...
        f.seek(-2, 1)         # ...jump back the read byte plus one more.
    last = f.readline()       # Read last line.

biggest = min(data)
smallest = max(data)
print(sum(data)/len(data))
print(last)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Once you've iterated through f, calls to `readline` will return `None`.

Comment: how the data are written in the file ? one value per line ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [slicing](http://techearth.net/python/index.php5?title=Python:Basics:Slices) to get only the 5 last numbers (I deleted all the irrelevant code):

```
with open('PastWinners.txt') as f:
    data = [float(line.rstrip()) for line in f]
print(sum(data[-5:])/len(data[-5:]))
```

the `data[-5:]` says take only the data from the 5-1 before last item to the last item.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. Just a side thing, would it be possible to make the print statement only display up to 2dp?

Comment: Sure. Change the last line to: `print("{0:0.2f}".format(sum(data[-5:])/len(data[-5:])))`

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file in reverse order and use *break* after 5 reads to get out from the loop. You can also just run 5 iteration of the loop while starting from the end of the file, so you will not have to use *break* at all.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301789/read-a-file-in-reverse-order-using-python) is how to read in reverse in Python.

Answer (score 0):

This will work when the file is less than 5 lines, too, and will format your average to 2 decimal places.

```
with open('PastWinners.txt') as f:
    data = [float(line.rstrip()) for line in f]

if len(data) > 5:
    data = data[-5:]

print min(data), max(data), "{:.2f}".format(sum(data)/len(data))
```