# Python: Read large file in reverse

Tags: python, reverse, mmap

I'm looking to achieve two things, reading large files which I've read up using `mmap` is suitable for this and reading the file in reverse (starting from the last line working up to the top).

I've tried both ways separately as follows:

```
f = open('syslog')
s = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)

#mmap method 
for line in iter(s.readline, ""):
    #search for string

#reading in reverse
for line in reversed(f.readlines()):
    #search for string
```

I'm struggling to incorporate both of these into the one and not sure of the best way to approach this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Uh, `f.readlines()` materializes your iterator into a list... Are you asking how to read through the memory-mapped file in reverse without materializing it into a list?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it's definitely not a trivial task. I found a library that does it, though: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/file-read-backwards

Comment: Ahh; I wrote it as an answer on [read a file in reverse order using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301789/read-a-file-in-reverse-order-using-python), but then deleted it (presumably on finding a bug). There are some answers that use `seek()` efficiently, though.

Comment: Anyway, I think that if you want to simply iterate over the lines, `mmap` is not necessary...

Comment: The end goal is essentially to search for various strings in a dictionary and print the line if found. I'm open to alternative suggestions. Would a for loop work if using something along the lines of  `if s.find(dict_key) != -1:` rather than iterating through each line. Not sure how I'd do it in reverse though

Comment: if you're only reading a large file, you shouldn't need to `mmap` it. Instead, open it normally and play games with `seek` to read it in reverse. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23646049/2958070) to easily do that.

Comment: What if you chunked the file (n lines) and then read each chunk in reverse?

Comment: a = buf[::-1] will cause MemoryError on big files, no idea why, it should load stuff into memory.