# read a number at the end of a file

Tags: python, file, text

I have a series of textfiles.
They all end with a float, without a preceding whitespace
`...foo123.456`. The float has an unbounded number of digits.

the files are large so I would like to avoid reading them completely in memory.
They have also different sizes.

How to avoid readgin the entire file?

Comment: You can use `file.seek`, hints available here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301789/read-a-file-in-reverse-order-using-python

Comment: the float may have arbitrary length though

Comment: @Liborio arbitrary length shouldn't matter as long as you know the *maximum* length. Just read a bunch of characters at the end of the file, then search backwards for the point where the number begins.

Comment: fair enough. but what if I didnt have the maximum length

Comment: uh, how arbitrary? There's a maximum, right? I guess you could just keep reading chunks until you hit something that's not digits or a `.`.

Comment: at very large scale it is a waste to read  even 1 byte extra per file...

Comment: That is not true. However, nothing stops you from using a chunk size of 1.

Comment: It is likely to be false, I/O is buffered and 1 extra byte probably won't matter as much as you think because the OS already reads in larger chunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read the last few bytes and use a regular expression in order to extract the float number.

Untested:

```
import re

with open('/path/to/file.txt') as input_file:
    input_file.seek(-100, 2)
    last_100_bytes = input_file.read()
    match = re.search(r'\D(\d+\.\d+)$', last_100_bytes)
    if match:
        print('The float is {}'.format(match.group(0)))
    else:
        print('no float found at the end of the file')
```

Comment: I think this is the answer after all...the over end of reading 100 bytes is insignificant as suggested by @Paulo Scardine