# Using the last one element in a large text file in Python

Tags: python, io

I have a 100 MB log file, but I only need the last element (all the elements are separated by '\n'.), the structure of the file is

```
{JSON}\n{JSON}\n...{JSON}\n
```

And the goal is to get the last JSON unit.

How to do this efficiently?

Thansk!

Comment: read in reverse. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301789/read-a-file-in-reverse-order-using-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a library called `tailer` (`pip install tailer`) which is similar to linux `tail file_path --lines=1` command and it meets my goal.

```
import tailer
# Read the last n lines
tail = tailer.tail(open(file_path), last_n_lines))
# tail is a list of last n lines
```

Or, using the `linechache` package, which is able to get the line by line number. To get the last line, first to count the number of lines in a text file.

```
total_line_number = sum(1 for line in open(file_path))
```

and then get the last line

```
import linecache
tail = linecache.getline(file_path, total_line_number)
```