# Python: Read last 'n' lines from a file

Tags: python, readline, readlines

I'm looking for a string `str` in a file and need the line after the occurrence of `str`. Right now, I am opening a file, reading all lines, saving them to a list and then looking up for that string in a list. Here's my code:

```
with open(file,'r') as file1:
    data = file1.readlines()

for num, line in enumerate(data,1):
    if 'str' in line:
        print line, data[num+1]
```

I know that `str` will be somewhere in the last 10 lines in `file`. So, I want to read and save the last 10 lines as a list rather than the whole file in the `data` variable.

I don't want to do `$tail file.dat > file1.dat` and go from there.

I want something like `reversed(readlines())` and save 10 lines to a list. How do I do it?

Comment: `reversed(readlines())[:10]`

Comment: I don't think the author really wants to save the lines reversed (last line first, and son). She wants to save the lines after the occurrence of `'str'` and preserve the order.

Comment: @Pie'Oh'Pah, that's right. I want the `len(data)` to be 10 and work from there.

Comment: python has negative integers. You can loop through a range of 10 and then store line[-i]

Comment: @Jérôme, `data = file1.readlines()[:-10]` reads the whole file except the last 10 lines.

Comment: @nacc001 said these: "'str' is somewhere in the last 10 lines" and "...need the lines after the occurrence of 'str'" but somehow later asked to "...save the last 10 lines as a list" a more complete answer can only be given when this conflict is cleared.

Comment: @nac001 You should have stated that you wanted to "save the rest of the lines in a file after an occurrence of 'str' as a list". The unclear statements made this question closed as being a duplicate.

Comment: I need the first 10 lines from the output of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2301792/9639680) answer. I can put it in a list.