# How can I find the last time a character was used in a txt file

Tags: python, file, text

I apologize if I didn't ask this question properly. It was kind of confusing. But for a visual example if I have this txt file:

```
| $100 on the first line
| $654 on the second line
| $123 on the third line
| $111 on the fourth line
```

How could I find the last time `$` was used to print out `111`?

Comment: How large does the text file get? Would it fit in memory? What have you tried yourself? Please share your code and the problems you had with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.rfind()` to get the last instance of a string (reversed first find) and then use that to index the string.

```
import io

file = "| $100 on the first line\n| $654 on the second line\n| $123 on the third line\n| $111 on the fourth line"
txt = io.StringIO(file).getvalue()

idx = txt.rfind('$')

#txt[idx+1:idx+4]
txt[idx+1:].split()[0]  #takes the complete first token instead of 3 characters
```

```
'111'
```

Comment: I have a question. What is the `idx+1` and `idx+4` part?

Comment: index of the last `$` character is `78`. You want the part of the string that exists between characters `79 to 79+4` which is '111'. You index a string as `string[start:stop]`. (in python start is inclusive and stop is exclusive)

Comment: Do you want to print `111` or you just want the position of the last `$`?

Comment: I just want to print out whatever is after the last `$` whether it be `111` or `111.46`

Comment: does that mean the complete sentence? `$111 on the fourth line` or just the token attached to `$`?

Comment: Updated my answer, try now. Now it simply takes the first attached word/number to `$` and returns it.

Comment: do let me know if that solved your question. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending of your needs bash may be more efficient for this. from your shell command line:

```
$ grep "$" file.txt | cut -d "$" -f2 | cut -d " " -f1 | tail -1
```

Output:

```
111
```

Answer (score -1):

for small files see this: [How to read a file in reverse order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301789/how-to-read-a-file-in-reverse-order)

for large files such that you need to consider diskIO, maybe try to seek() to end of file and read back (in chunks)