# How to quickly get the last line from a .csv file over a network drive?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, network-programming, python-os

I store thousands of time series in `.csv` files on a network drive. Before I update the files, I first get the last line of the file to see the timestamp and then I update with data after that timestamp. How can I quickly get the last line of a `.csv` file over a network drive so that I don't have to load the entire huge `.csv` file only to use the last line?

Comment: I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37551666/1367204)

Answer (score 6):

There is a nifty `reversed` tool for this, assuming you are using the built-in `csv` module:

[how to read a csv file in reverse order in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933838/how-to-read-a-csv-file-in-reverse-order-in-python)

In short:

```
import csv
with open('some_file.csv', 'r') as f:
    for row in reversed(list(csv.reader(f))):
        print(', '.join(row))
```

In my test file of:

```
1:   test, 1
2:   test, 2
3:   test, 3
```

This outputs:

```
test, 3
test, 2
test, 1
```

Comment: I feel like this still will read the entire file into memory, while what I need is just to read the last row into memory so that it doesn't waste time reading unnecessary stuff into memory.

Comment: You could try being more explicit, without iterating over each row by indexing:
`print(', '.join(reversed(list(csv.reader(f))[-1])))`
I am sure there is a better way to do it, but that is what comes to mind...

Comment: I just tested that and it was the same amount of time =(

Comment: There was another thread you may want to check out... haven't tried it, but it might be worth while... uses `seek`:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260273/most-efficient-way-to-search-the-last-x-lines-of-a-file-in-python