# How to find last line in csv file when using DictReader

Tags: python, json, csv

I have the following code that transforms a .csv file to a .json one. Because I have multiple csv records, and I will need to operate on multiple json objects, I was thinking of creating an array. The resulting file looks good, EXCEPT that the last record has a trailing comma. I have been trying to figure out how to not include that comma, but have not been able to do so.

```
csvfile = open('file.csv','r')
jsonfile = open('file.json','w')

reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
jsonfile.write('[')

for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, jsonfile)
    jsonfile.write(',')
    jsonfile.write('\n')
jsonfile.write(']')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the dict records produced by the `DictReader` generator into a list first before dumping it as JSON:

```
jsonfile.write(json.dumps(list(reader)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=open('file.txt','rb')
lines = a.readlines()
if lines:
    first_line = lines[:1]
    last_line = lines[-1]
```

check this : 
[StackOverFlow question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681865/how-to-quickly-get-the-last-line-from-a-csv-file-over-a-network-drive)
[StackOverFlow question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346430/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-get-first-and-last-line-of-a-text-file/37551666#37551666)

Comment: Can you please add more explanation on why this is answer ?