# json.dumps adding double quotes and backslash

Tags: python, json

I'm converting a csv file with multiple records to a file with a json array. Solution is [How to find last line in csv file when using DictReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54446144/how-to-find-last-line-in-csv-file-when-using-dictreader/54446254#54446254). This works fine, except that resulting json in file has backslash (\) and double-quotes; i.e. it's escaping the strings. For example:

> {"Test Name": "Basic Tcp IPerf Test", " \"Status\"": "PASS", " \"Test
>   Start Time\"": "20190103 08:07:41.662", " \"Test End Time\"":
>   "20190103 08:08:44.051", " \"Throughput\"": "2095.2746", "
>   \"Jitter\"": "", " \"Packet Loss %\"": "", " \"Compute/VM\"": "SendVm
>   (x.x.x.x)", " \"Statistics Sampling Start Time\"": "03 Jan 2019
>   08:07:44", " \"Statistics Sampling End Time\"": "03 Jan 2019
>   08:08:42", " \"Min CPU\"": "0", " \"Max CPU\"": "2", " \"Avg CPU\"":
>   "1", " \"Avg Memory (MB)\" ": "7758"}

Is there a way to write out that json without that escaping? 
Code:

```
csvfile = open('fiile.csv','r')
jsonfile = open('file.json','w')

reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

jsonfile.write(json.dumps(list(reader)))
```

Comment: If you just do `print(list(reader))`, does that _also_ have double quotes? Or possibly two layers of alternating quotes, ex. `'"status"'`? I suspect the problem is with the csv file, not the json.

Comment: @Kevin Could be right about .csv file. Here's the header and the first record:
"Test Name", "Status", "Test Start Time", "Test End Time", "Throughput", "Jitter", "Packet Loss %", "Compute/VM", "Statistics Sampling Start Time", "Statistics Sampling End Time", "Min CPU", "Max CPU", "Avg CPU", "Avg Memory (MB)"
"Basic Tcp IPerf Test",PASS,20190103 08:07:41.662,20190103 08:08:44.051,2095.2746,,,"SendVm (x.x.x.x)",03 Jan 2019 08:07:44,03 Jan 2019 08:08:42,0,2,1,7758

Comment: @Kevin Also, print(list(reader)) also has double quotes though no escape backslashes: (' "Status"', 'PASS'), (' "Test Start Time"', '20190103 08:07:41.662')

Comment: If you put `print(list(reader))` on the line after `jsonfile.write(json.dumps(list(reader)))`, I would expect the output to be blank. Readers can only iterate over the file once. Calling list on it a second time will give only an empty list, since the pointer is at the end of the file. I meant that you should replace `jsonfile.write(json.dumps(list(reader)))` entirely with `print(list(reader))`.

Comment: @Kevin yep, caught that, see my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your csv file is formatted in a way that confuses the default csv parser. In particular, your columns are separated by both a comma *and* a space:

```
           comma
           v
"Test Name", "Status"
            ^
            space
```

This makes the parser assume that all the text following the comma is part of the value, including the space and the quote mark.

One possible solution is to specify a value for the `skipinitialspace` argument when opening the DictReader.

```
import csv
import json

csvfile = open('fiile.csv','r')
jsonfile = open('file.json','w')

reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, skipinitialspace=True)
jsonfile.write(json.dumps(list(reader)))
```

Then the parser should understand that the space and quote aren't part of the value. Result:

```
[{"Test Name": "Basic Tcp IPerf Test", "Status": "PASS", "Test Start Time": "20190103 08:07:41.662", "Test End Time": "20190103 08:08:44.051", "Throughput": "2095.2746", "Jitter": "", "Packet Loss %": "", "Compute/VM": "SendVm (x.x.x.x)", "Statistics Sampling Start Time": "03 Jan 2019 08:07:44", "Statistics Sampling End Time": "03 Jan 2019 08:08:42", "Min CPU": "0", "Max CPU": "2", "Avg CPU": "1", "Avg Memory (MB)": "7758"}]
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't catch that extra space in the CSV. Your solution worked great.