# Python - Reversing a Whole File

Tags: python, file, reverse

I need to be able to reverse a whole file, or at least the contents of it. My code so far is:

```
def reverse_file(of, rf):
     oldfile = open(of, 'r')
     reversefile = open(rf, 'w')
     filedata = oldfile.read()
     rdata = str_reverse(filedata)
     reversefile.write(rdata)
     oldfile.close()
     reversefile.close()
```

The problem is I need to define `str_reverse` and I'm not sure how to create a function that reverses everything. Any help?

Comment: Do you just want each line to be reversed, or do you want to switch the first line with the last line, or both?

Comment: @NolenRoyalty Everything should be reversed, not too sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to reverse the entire file, you can just call `write` with `data[::-1]`

```
def reverse_file(of, rf):
    with open(of) as oldfile:
        with open(rf, "w") as reversefile:
            reversefile.write(oldfile.read()[::-1])
```

example:

```
% cat testdata
line1
line2
line3
% cat reverse_file.py
def reverse_file(of, rf):
    with open(of) as oldfile:
        with open(rf, "w") as reversefile:
            reversefile.write(oldfile.read()[::-1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    reverse_file("testdata", "newdata")
% python reverse_file.py
% cat newdata

3enil
2enil
1enil
```

Comment: +1 , `with open(of) as oldfile, open(rf, "w") as reversefile:` will also work fine.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary thanks, I was wondering what the syntax would be if you wanted both the `with`s on the same line.

Answer (score 3):

To support files that do not fit in memory (based on [@Darius Bacon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/260433/4279)):

```
import os
from io import DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE

def reverse_blocks(file, blocksize=DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE):
    """Yield blocks from the file in reverse order."""
    file.seek(0, os.SEEK_END) # move file position to the end
    position = file.tell()
    while position > 0:
        delta = min(blocksize, position)
        file.seek(position - delta, os.SEEK_SET)
        yield file.read(delta)
        position -= blocksize

# reverse input and write it to output
with open("input", "rb") as infile, open("output", "wb") as outfile:
    for block in reverse_blocks(infile):
        outfile.write(block[::-1])
```