# Python: Reading a file and reverse all lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, reverse

So I'm trying to reverse all lines, but instead I get totaly strange reverse, it puts 4th line on the 1st line with the 5 line...

How file looks before reversing:

```
1 line
2 line
3 line
4 line
5 line
```

After reversing:

```
5 line4 line
3 line
2 line
1 line
```

Here is the code:

```
    file = open(filename, "r")
    list = file.readlines()
    file.close()

    list.reverse()

    file = open(filename, "w")
    for value in list:
        file.write(value)
    file.close()
```

Comment: related: [Read a file in reverse order using python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2301789/4279). See also [`reversed_lines()` function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/260433/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you didn't have the end line sign in the last line (the `'\n'`).
It could be fixed easily by adding `'\n'` when needed:

```
file = open(filename, "w")
    for value in list:
         file.write(value.rstrip() + "\n")
    file.close()
```

Comment: use `with`-statement to close the file even if an exception happens: `with open(filename, 'w') as file: file.writelines(map(str.rstrip, lines))`

Answer (score 3):

Every line of the file has a newline character `\n` at the end of it, except for the very last line.

The simplest way would be to do this:

```
file.open(filename,'r')
lines = file.read().split("\n")
file.close()
file = open(filename, "w")
file.write("\n".join(lines[::-1]))
file.close()
```

You could also try using `str.strip()` or `str.rstrip()` to remove all whitespace from the ends of a string or just the right end.  This, however, would also remove spaces, tabs, etc.