# Python3.4 : Multiprocessing variable functions

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am running this code below using multiprocessing to run `ticker_list` through a request and parsing program faster.  The following code works, but it is very slow.  I am not so sure that this is the correct usage of multiprocessing.  If there is a more efficient way to do this then please let me know.

```
ticker_list = []

with open('/home/a73nk-xce/Documents/Python/SharkFin/SP500_Fin/SP_StockChar/ticker.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for rows in spamreader:
        pass

    for eachTicker in rows:
        ticker_list.append(eachTicker)

def final_function(ticker):
    try:
        GetFinData.CashData(ticker_list)


    except Exception as e:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    p = mp.Process(target=final_function, args=(ticker_list,))
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

if your ticker file is large
(judging by the path name, it may be)

using the csv reader is a waste of time.
it does not suport seek, so the only way you can get to the last line is

```
    for row in spamreader:
        pass
```

since after this "row" will contain the last row in the file..

you can see here: [Most efficient way to search the last x lines of a file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260273/most-efficient-way-to-search-the-last-x-lines-of-a-file-in-python)
that it's possible to retrieve only the last lines in the file, and then parse it with the csv module afterward..

This will save some computation time..