# Decoding Unicode text backwards

Tags: python, text, unicode, encoding

Many text encodings have the property that you can go through encoded text *backwards* and still be able to decode it. ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32 all have this property. This lets you do handy things like read the last line of a file without reading all the lines before it, or go backwards a few lines from your current position in a file.

Unfortunately, Python doesn't seem to come with any way to decode a file backwards. You can't `read` backwards, or `seek` by character quantity in an encoded file. The decoders in the [`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) module support incremental decoding *forwards*, but not backwards. There doesn't seem to be any "UTF-8-backwards" codec I could feed UTF-8 bytes to in reverse order.

I could probably implement the codec-dependent character boundary synchronization myself, read binary chunks backward, and feed properly-aligned chunks to appropriate decoders from the `codecs` module, but that sounds like the kind of thing where a non-expert would miss some subtle detail and not notice the output is wrong.

Is there any simple way to decode text backward in Python with existing tools?

---

Several people appear to have missed the point that **reading the entire file to do this defeats the purpose**. While I'm clarifying things, I might as well add that **this needs to work for variable-length encodings**, too. **UTF-8 support is a must**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read a file in reverse order using python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301789/read-a-file-in-reverse-order-using-python)

Comment: @gravity: That reads the entire file. I'm specifically trying not to do that.

Comment: There's a specific community wiki answer there that involves reading in chunks.  Please take a look at it at this direct link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260273/most-efficient-way-to-search-the-last-x-lines-of-a-file-in-python/260433#260433

Comment: @gravity: That doesn't work with Unicode.

Comment: @user2357112 - You've answered your own question: "*implement the codec-dependent character boundary synchronization myself, read binary chunks backward, and feed properly-aligned chunks to appropriate decoders from the codecs module,*" That's going to be the simplest way.

Comment: @Robᵩ: It definitely looks that way, but I'm hoping there's something I missed.

Comment: P.s. the UTF-8 boundary test is easy. The first byte of a chunk must not satisfy `(x & 0xc0) == 0x80`.

Comment: if all you want is to read *lines* from the end of a file without loading the entire file into memory then the implementation may be simple: [read lines e.g., using `mmap` (replace `b'\n'` for non-ascii -based encodings and use `.rfind()` for speed)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6813975/4279) and call `line.decode(encoding)` on each line.

Answer (score 5):

Absent a general-purpose solution, here is one specific to utf-8:

```
def rdecode(it):
    buffer = []
    for ch in it:
        och = ord(ch)
        if not (och & 0x80):
            yield ch.decode('utf-8')
        elif not (och & 0x40):
            buffer.append(ch)
        else:
            buffer.append(ch)
            yield ''.join(reversed(buffer)).decode('utf-8')
            buffer = []

utf8 = 'ho math\xc4\x93t\xc4\x93s hon \xc4\x93gap\xc4\x81 ho I\xc4\x93sous'
print utf8.decode('utf8')
for i in rdecode(reversed(utf8)):
    print i,
print ""
```

Result:

```
$ python x.py 
ho mathētēs hon ēgapā ho Iēsous
s u o s ē I   o h   ā p a g ē   n o h   s ē t ē h t a m   o h
```

Comment: That looks like what I was thinking of for the "implement it myself" case, although it doesn't have any of the chunking optimization you'd want for operating on real files. I guess a lot of the work I didn't want to deal with was really in multiple codec support and writing a convenient, efficient file object that supports `read`-ing forwards and backwards and backwards iteration; for just UTF-8, the decoding itself isn't too bad.