# How to implement a pythonic equivalent of tail -F?

Tags: python, file, tail

What is the pythonic way of watching the tail end of a growing file for the occurrence of certain keywords?

In shell I might say:

```
tail -f "$file" | grep "$string" | while read hit; do
    #stuff
done
```

Comment: Somewhat similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136168/tail-a-file-with-python

Comment: Those two questions seem identical, but this one is about constantly monitoring a file for new lines, whereas the other question is about reading the last x lines

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well, the simplest way would be to constantly read from the file, check what's new and test for hits.

```
import time

def watch(fn, words):
    fp = open(fn, 'r')
    while True:
        new = fp.readline()
        # Once all lines are read this just returns ''
        # until the file changes and a new line appears

        if new:
            for word in words:
                if word in new:
                    yield (word, new)
        else:
            time.sleep(0.5)

fn = 'test.py'
words = ['word']
for hit_word, hit_sentence in watch(fn, words):
    print "Found %r in line: %r" % (hit_word, hit_sentence)
```

This solution with `readline` works if you know your data will appear in lines.

If the data is some sort of stream you need a buffer, larger than the largest `word` you're looking for, and fill it first. It gets a bit more complicated that way...

Comment: I'm a little sketched out by repeatedly opening the file. You can use os.stat to tell you whether the file is modified.

Comment: Look again; open is only called once.  readline gets called repeatedly.

Answer (score 7):

```
def tail(f):
    f.seek(0, 2)

    while True:
        line = f.readline()

        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue

        yield line

def process_matches(matchtext):
    while True:
        line = (yield)  
        if matchtext in line:
            do_something_useful() # email alert, etc.


list_of_matches = ['ERROR', 'CRITICAL']
matches = [process_matches(string_match) for string_match in list_of_matches]    

for m in matches: # prime matches
    m.next()

while True:
    auditlog = tail( open(log_file_to_monitor) )
    for line in auditlog:
        for m in matches:
            m.send(line)
```

I use this to monitor log files.  In the full implementation, I keep list_of_matches in a configuration file so it can be used for multiple purposes.  On my list of enhancements is support for regex instead of a simple 'in' match.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: as the comment below notes, `O_NONBLOCK` doesn't work for files on disk.  This will still help if anyone else comes along looking to tail data coming from a socket or named pipe or another process, but it **doesn't answer the actual question that was asked**.  Original answer remains below for posterity.  (Calling out to tail and grep will work, but is a non-answer of sorts anyway.)

Either open the file with `O_NONBLOCK` and use `select` to poll for read availability and then `read` to read the new data and the string methods to filter lines on the end of a file...or just use the `subprocess` module and let `tail` and `grep` do the work for you just as you would in the shell.

Comment: Non-blocking IO is not supported for files on most (if not all) OS. That includes Linux and FreeBSD. If it were, combination of non-blocking IO and poll/select/whatever would be the same as blocking reading, which doesn't do what the OP needs.

Comment: @WGH: Good point!  I think I learned that after having written this, but it's important to note for anyone who comes along to this question later on, so I've prefaced my answer with a disclaimer to that effect.

Answer (score 3):

You can use select to poll for new contents in a file.

```
def tail(filename, bufsize = 1024):
    fds = [ os.open(filename, os.O_RDONLY) ]
    while True:
        reads, _, _ = select.select(fds, [], [])
        if 0 < len(reads):
            yield os.read(reads[0], bufsize)
```

Comment: You cannot use select to poll files for new data - only sockets. See: http://docs.python.org/library/select.html, first paragraph last sentence: It cannot be used on regular files to determine whether a file has grown since it was last read.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there's a package for that: https://github.com/kasun/python-tail

Answer (score 2):

you can use [pytailf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytailf/1.0) : Simple python tail -f wrapper

```
from tailf import tailf    

for line in tailf("myfile.log"):
    print line
```

Comment: Dont waste your time with tailf, it's calling "/usr/bin/tail" internally, which is surely not what you want.

Comment: "*`# Mwa-ha-ha, this is easiest way. Hardly portable to windowz, but who cares?
TAILF_COMMAND = ['/usr/bin/tail', '-F', '-n']`*"

Answer (score 1):

If you can't constraint the problem to work for a line-based read, you need to resort to blocks.

This should work:

```
import sys

needle = "needle"

blocks = []

inf = sys.stdin

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    inf = open(sys.argv[1])

while True:
    block = inf.read()
    blocks.append(block)
    if len(blocks) >= 2:
        data = "".join((blocks[-2], blocks[-1]))
    else:
        data = blocks[-1]

    # attention, this needs to be changed if you are interested
    # in *all* matches separately, not if there was any match ata all
    if needle in data:
        print "found"
        blocks = []
    blocks[:-2] = []

    if block == "":
        break
```

The challenge lies in ensuring that you match needle even if it's separated by two block-boundaries.

Comment: Good catch; I swim in log files all day, sometimes I forget that not all data comes in lines.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there's no equivalent to "tail" in the Python function list. Solution would be to use tell() (get file size) and read() to work out the ending lines.

This blog post (not by me) has the function written out, looks appropriate to me!
http://www.manugarg.com/2007/04/real-tailing-in-python.html

Answer (score -1):

If you just need a dead simple Python 3 solution for processing the lines of a text file as they're written, and you don't need Windows support, this worked well for me:

```
import subprocess
def tailf(filename):
    #returns lines from a file, starting from the beginning
    command = "tail -n +1 -F " + filename
    p = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    for line in p.stdout:
        yield line
for line in tailf("logfile"):
    #do stuff
```

It blocks waiting for new lines to be written, so this isn't suitable for asynchronous use without some modifications.

Comment: it would also work on windows in case Git packages are in %path%

Comment: My understanding is that the question wasn't asking for wrapping `tail`, but is rather looking for the equivalent in plain Python.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `collections.deque` to implement tail.

From http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#deque-recipes ...

```
def tail(filename, n=10):
    'Return the last n lines of a file'
    return deque(open(filename), n)
```

Of course, this reads the entire file contents, but it's a neat and terse way of implementing tail.

Comment: That answers a different question.