# Is Python's seek() on OS X broken?

Tags: python, macos, seek

I'm trying to implement a simple method to read new lines from a log file each time the method is called.

I've looked at the various suggestions both on stackoverflow (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703640/how-to-implement-a-pythonic-equivalent-of-tail-f)) and elsewhere for simulating "tail" functionality; most involve using `readline()` to read in new lines as they're appended to the file. It should be simple enough, but can't get it to work properly on OS X 10.6.4 with the included Python 2.6.1.

To get to the heart of the problem, I tried the following:

1. Open two terminal windows.
2. In one, create a text file "test.log" with three lines:

   ```
   one
   two
   three
   ```
3. In the other, start python and execute the following code:

   ```
   Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Feb 11 2010, 00:51:29) 
   [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>> import os
   >>> os.stat('test.log')
   posix.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=23465217, st_dev=234881025L, st_nlink=1, st_uid=666, st_gid=20, st_size=14, st_atime=1281782739, st_mtime=1281782738, st_ctime=1281782738)
   >>> log = open('test.log')
   >>> log.tell()
   0
   >>> log.seek(0,2)
   >>> log.tell()
   14
   >>>
   ```

   So we see with the `tell()` that `seek(0,2)` brought us to the end of the file as reported by `os.stat()`, byte 14.
4. In the first shell, add another two lines to "test.log" so that it looks like this:

   ```
   one
   two
   three
   four
   five
   ```
5. Go back to the second shell, and execute the following code:

   ```
   >>> os.stat('test.log')
   posix.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=23465260, st_dev=234881025L, st_nlink=1, st_uid=666, st_gid=20, st_size=24, st_atime=1281783089, st_mtime=1281783088, st_ctime=1281783088)
   >>> log.seek(0,2)
   >>> log.tell()
   14
   >>>
   ```

Here we see from `os.stat()` that the file's size is now 24 bytes, but seeking to the end of the file somehow still points to byte 14?? I've tried the same on Ubuntu with Python 2.5 and it works as I expect. I tried with 2.5 on my Mac, but got the same results as with 2.6.

I must be missing something fundamental here. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get adifferent result if you use os.SEEK_END instead of the literal 2?

Comment: Macha - no difference. Problem is my test scenario...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you adding two more lines to the file?

Most text editors will go through operations a lot like this:

```
fd = open(filename, read)
file_data = read(fd)
close(fd)
/* you edit your file, and save it */
unlink(filename)
fd = open(filename, write, create)
write(fd, file_data)
```

The file is different. (Check it with `ls -li`; the inode number will change for almost every text editor.)

If you *append* to the log file using your shell's `>>` redirection, it'll work exactly as it should:

```
$ echo one >> test.log
$ echo two >> test.log
$ echo three >> test.log
$ ls -li test.log
671147 -rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold 14 2010-08-14 04:15 test.log
$ echo four >> test.log
$ ls -li test.log
671147 -rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold 19 2010-08-14 04:15 test.log

>>> log=open('test.log')
>>> log.tell()
0
>>> log.seek(0,2)
>>> log.tell()
19

$ echo five >> test.log
$ echo six >> test.log

>>> log.seek(0,2)
>>> log.tell()
28
```

Note that the `tail(1)` command has an `-F` command line option to handle the case where the file is changed, but a file by the same name exists. (Great for watching log files that might be periodically rotated.)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no, your assumptions are.

Your text editor is creating a new file with the same name, not modifying the old file in place. You can see in your `stat` result that the `st_ino` is different. If you were to do `os.fstat(log.fileno())`, you'd get the old size and old `st_ino`.

If you want to check for this in your implementation of `tail`, periodically compare the `st_ino` of the `stat` and `fstat` results. If they differ, there's a new file with the same name.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that the file was being recreated. Thanks!