# Paramiko - sftp client used to get last line of log file

Tags: python, file, ssh, paramiko

I'd like to use paramiko and an sftp client to poll a log file for the last line. I'm aware of sshtail module in python, but using it goes against the coding standards where I am right now.

I previously used that and now I'm wondering how to go about reading the last line of a log file?

Thanks,

Parth

EDIT2:

```
try: 
    self.logger.info("SSH Log: trying to connect to: " + self.ssh_server_ip + "," + str(self.ssh_port) + "," + self.ssh_username + "," + self.ssh_password) 
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(self.ssh_server_ip, self.log_server_port, self.ssh_username, self.ssh_password)
    self.logger.info("SSH LOG: Deleting files from HTTP Upload Server")
    sftp = client.open_sftp()
    remote_command = "tail -n1 /var/log/apache2/access.log"
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(remote_command)
    last_line = stdout.read()
    old_line = last_line
    while 1:
        remote_command = "tail -n1 /var/log/apache2/access.log"
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(remote_command)
        last_line = stdout.read()
        if last_line != old_line:
            finish_line = last_line
            break
    self.logger.info("SSH Log: closing connection")
    sftp.close()
    client.close()
    except Exception, e:
        self.logger.error(str(e))
        self.logger.error("Failed to delete file on HTTP server: " + str(e))
    except:
        self.logger.error("Failed to delete file on HTTP server")
```

Comment: I'm assuming the file is on a remote server then? What have you tried so far?

Comment: It's on a remote linux server running Ubuntu 11.10. I've just used the sshtail module to tail the file. I should only expect a non blank log. Once I get it, I save it and parse it.

Comment: I meant do you have any code to post, which is your attempt to solve the problem? It's expected that you make some attempt first, rather than just asking for code: [ask]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python to emulate remote tail -f?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680055/python-to-emulate-remote-tail-f)

Comment: I don't think it is, because i must use SFTP client in paramiko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be faster and easier to just call `tail -n1` on the file remotely via the shell and read its stdout. Something like:

```
remote_command = "tail -n1 /var/log/apache2/access.log"
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(remote_command)
last_line = stdout.read()
```

Comment: Should I just do a tail -f actually? Can you please provide code that does what you're asking?

Comment: `tail -f` is *follow* mode - probably not what you want. I've updated my response with some code.

Comment: -n1 would get the last line of the file. I'm waiting for a file to download and the access log would indicate that it's finished downloading. So how would that work with tail -f

Comment: ahh. You could poll it with `-n1` (just put it inside a loop), but it can have a lot of overhead. Im not quite sure you will be able to do a check inside stdout.read() because that is a blocking call that takes no options for testing/waiting AFAIK.

Comment: If I poll it with -n1 in a loop, won't it read the last line already written to the file? ideally i'd like to poll the file for a new line, obtain the immediate line and parse that later on

Comment: what do you mean by 'immediate line'? I thought you were trying to read the last line written to file. Now that I look at it, your while loop is in some infinite loop? Is it expected to throw an exception? Where is the delete actually happening in your code?

Comment: I ended up using a variation of your code which i have posted in my original post. Thanks for your help