# how to get the exact position in a file and print lines from that position?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, file-handling, file-pointer

I am trying to update a logfile continuously and I am accessing that logfile in `log_parser.py` file like below:

```
****log_parser.py****
import time
last_pos=0
while True:
    f=open(r".\log_file.log","r")
    f.seek(last_pos)
    for i in f.readlines():
        print i
        print "****************************"
    else:
        last_pos=f.tell()
        time.sleep(1)
        continue
```

Now I am trying to print log lines continuously. If there are no log lines it will record last position value and I `seek()` that position each iteration, but that gives me the wrong output.

```
****log_file.log****
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
.
.
.
.
.
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
```

I am appending those lines dynamically into that logfile.

```
 ****Excpected output*************
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 ***********************
 bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
 *************************
 cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
 **************************
 and upto zzzzzz
```

but now I am getting

```
  ***I am Getting************
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  **********************
  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
  *********************
  cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
  ************************
  dddddddddddddddd
  *************************
  dddddddddddd
  *******************
  eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
  ***********************************
  upto zzzzz
```

but in between `f.tell()` method returns the pointer and `f.seek()` method seeks the position of middle of the line.

Can anyone please help solve this?

Comment: Suggest you [edit] your question and use different sample data. It's difficult to tell the original lines from those appended with what you currently have. Also (don't know if it matters) I noticed you never close the file you open. Suggest you add that or use a `with` statement to have it done automatically.

Comment: I am just reading the file right ? then what is the need for close a file

Comment: Every `open()` uses up some resources and your code is doing it a _lot_, plus you're having weird problems...just say'in.

Comment: Sorry don't know how to fix your code. However the answers to this question [_How to implement a pythonic equivalent of tail -F?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703640/how-to-implement-a-pythonic-equivalent-of-tail-f) may be helpful.