# Changing Scripts from Linux to Python - Automation

Tags: python, linux, automation, automated-tests

i use the following commands and form a script to automate servers using Linux
now i would like to automate it in python,i dont know how to write commands for these
as i am new to python.

```
    echo "DISK SPACE"
    echo "--------------------- "
    df -kh

    echo "CPU UTILIZATION"
    prstat 1 1

    echo "MEMORY UTILIZATION"
    echo "---------------------    "
    vmstat 

    echo "LINK STATUS"
    echo "---------------------    "
    egrep -i "link||service" logs/septel.log|tail -20

    echo "Restart log"
    echo "---------------------    "
    tail -10  //newlogs/restart.log

    echo "MENU"
    echo "---------------------    "
    echo "0"|/operations/Menu.pl

    dat=`date +%Y%m%d`
    echo "==================================   "
    echo "EOD "
    cat /b-eod/eodclearlog.log

    echo "mart STP"
    echo "---------------------    "
    tail /logs/mart-stp.log

    echo "TNSPING STATUS"
    echo "=========================================   "
    tnsping rwdb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different way to solve your problem. If you need a quick one, you need to know that any shell entry can be used through python subprocess:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["ls", "-l"])
```

But if you have time, and you want to power the python API, you should give a look to the OS and SYS libraries:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html

Anything written with these lib should be usable from Unix or windows.

And to replicate the behaviour or more fancy command, like `tail`, you will need to look a bit around. For example this question provide several suggestions: [How to implement a pythonic equivalent of tail -F?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703640/how-to-implement-a-pythonic-equivalent-of-tail-f)

Like using the library `tailf`.