# How to write last 50 lines from one file to another Python

Tags: python

I am creating an email response to an overnight build, I want to get the last 50 lines from the results file and place it into a summary file. The code that I have done is below, can anyone help?

```
def email_success():

    fp = open(results_file, 'r')

    sum_file = (fp.readlines()[-50:])
    fp.close()

    myfile = open(result_summary,'w')

    myfile.write(sum_file)
    myfile.close()
```

I have got the error message below when trying this code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "email_success.py", line 76, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': myObject = email_success()
  File "email_success.py", line 45, in email_success
    myfile = open(result_summary,'w')
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found
```

Thanks

The results summary is a variable that stores an address.

```
result_summary = (t, 'results_summary.txt')
```

Sorry made a stupid mistake, I forgot to add os.path.join

```
result_summary = os.path.join(t, 'results_summary.txt')
```

Thanks for the help

@alok It is a directory address, I forgot to add the os.join to make it one string. This is what was causing the error

Comment: replace `write` with `writelines`, and get rid of `()` surrounding the `readlines()` call.

Comment: @chris: What do you think `open((t, 'results_summary.txt'), 'w')` means?

Comment: If you're using linux/unix you could use `tail -n 50 input.txt > output.txt`.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136168/get-last-n-lines-of-a-file-with-python-similar-to-tail.  Likely homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result_summary` is a tuple, it needs to be either a `str` or buffer. Your explanation has nothing to do with the error you posted.

Answer (score 5):

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found
```

Error says its expect string or buffer but you are passing `tuple`, so just join it with `""` to make it to string

So, Try

```
sum_file = "".join(fp.readlines()[-50:])
```

**UPDATE**: because OP updated the question

if `result_summary = (t, 'results_summary.txt')`

Try

```
myfile = open(result_summary[1],'w')
```

Answer (score 2):

It's open() raising the exception though... how did you define result_summary?

Answer (score 1):

```
result_summary = (t, 'results_summary.txt')
```

and

```
 myfile = open(result_summary,'w')
```

means

```
 myfile = open((t, 'results_summary.txt'),'w')
```

which obviously won't work, try:

```
 myfile = open(result_summary[1],'w')
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

`fp.readlines()` method returns a list of lines.
Therefore you can't apply `[-50:]` operator.

Comment: That's wrong, you can definitely do `a[-50:]` when `a` is of type `list`.