# Read last n lines of file (tail) without reading it line-by-line?

Tags: python, file, file-io, tail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get last n lines of a file with Python, similar to tail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136168/get-last-n-lines-of-a-file-with-python-similar-to-tail)

Hello,

How can I have Python return the last n lines of a file without reading it line by line?

Comment: This is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136168/get-last-n-lines-of-a-file-with-python-similar-to-tail

Comment: Did not see the duplicate. Thanks (will close).

Comment: This title says one thing (read the file backwards), but its details and the duplicate link say another (just read the last n line tail). Title needs to be fixed otherwise this messes up canonicals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

- Use [`seek()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) to get something like the last 4096 bytes of a file.
- See how many newlines you have in those bytes. If you have `n` or more, then you're done. If you have fewer, then read the previous 4096 bytes until you're done.

Not sure if there's a built-in way to do this.