# Breaking inline for loop on condition

Tags: python-3.x, loops, if-statement

I want to find the first number k such that the sum of squares of all naturals up to that number is divisible by 200.

Normal solution:

```
sum = 0
for k in range(1, max+1):
    sum += k**2
    if sum % 200 == 0:
        return k
```

I have a one-liner:

```
print(sum([i^2 for i in range(1, 1000)]))
```

But I want to break this loop as soon as this sum is divisible by 200.

Is it possible to do this?

**EDIT**

I've seen this Q&A on [break list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572833/break-list-comprehension) but it breaks when a value inside the list fulfills some requirement. I want to break when the `sum` of all values that have been iterated over, reaches some requirement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [break list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572833/break-list-comprehension)

Comment: @StephenRauch - There may be something there, but it only shows how to break on a condition relating to each value inside the list. I want to break once the *sum* of these has reached a certain point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stopping a Reduce() operation mid way. Functional way of doing partial running sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130352/stopping-a-reduce-operation-mid-way-functional-way-of-doing-partial-running-s)