# Scoping in Python 'for' loops

Tags: python, scope

I'm not asking about Python's scoping rules; I understand generally *how* scoping works in Python for loops. My question is *why* the design decisions were made in this way. For example (no pun intended):

```
for foo in xrange(10):
    bar = 2
print(foo, bar)
```

The above will print (9,2).

This strikes me as weird: 'foo' is really just controlling the loop, and 'bar' was defined inside the loop. I can understand why it might be necessary for 'bar' to be accessible outside the loop (otherwise, for loops would have very limited functionality). What I don't understand is why it is necessary for the control variable to remain in scope after the loop exits. In my experience, it simply clutters the global namespace and makes it harder to track down errors that would be caught by interpreters in other languages.

Comment: If you don't want the `for` loop cluttering your global namespace, wrap it in a function. Closures galore!

Comment: Unless you're running a loop in the global namespace (uncommon), it's cluttering a *local* namespace.

Comment: If this didn't exist, how would you continue processing later at the point you left off inside the loop?  Just define the control variable *before* the loop?

Comment: @endolith Yeah... Why not require that?

Comment: @StevenLu: because that would be more work for little to no benefit?

Comment: well people are just gonna prefer what they're used to doing. I'd say this sort of thing hurts the python coder who gets used to this sort of thing and has to go through a painful process when switching to a different language. For the rest of us, it's a neat little shortcut I suppose.

Comment: @StevenLu: So we shouldn't make nice languages, because then the pain of switching to crappier languages is even more apparent? :)

Comment: No, not having to init these variables makes python better and most would be inclined to agree. gotta weigh the options

Comment: This scares the hell out of me for a language which otherwise uses white space as an "elegant" way of managing scope. It makes me question whether my any of my "scoped" variables are truly in their own scope.

Comment: Is this good memory-wise? And if Python does eventually get rid of them, is it safe to use such variables throughout the program?

Comment: I have to use python after 30+ years of c and c++. It seems to me that using a lot of small functions (e.g. a function per loop)  is the only way to avoid maintenance headaches that can arise from scoping rules.

Comment: This cost me in actual damages for a project I did with Jupyter, which had a line like `for y in ys: plot(X, y)` where `y` overrode a preceding label variable that was used further down

Comment: @endolith can you please elaborate, how can I continue processing later at the point you left off inside the loop? I want to use the index left off after coming out of the loop.

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal So just use the index after coming out of the loop

Comment: Sorry @endolith actually i just realised that i was expecting work of conditional loop from for loop that should be done with while loop in python unlike java

Answer (score 157, accepted):

The likeliest answer is that it just keeps the grammar simple, hasn't been a stumbling block for adoption, and many have been happy with not having to disambiguate the scope to which a name belongs when assigning to it within a loop construct.  Variables are not declared within a scope, it is implied by the location of assignment statements.  The [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#global) keyword exists just for this reason (to signify that assignment is done at a global scope).

**Update**

Here's a good discussion on the topic:  http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2008-October/002109.html

> Previous proposals to make for-loop
> variables local to the loop have
> stumbled on the problem of existing
> code that relies on the loop variable
> keeping its value after exiting the
> loop, and it seems that this is
> regarded as a desirable feature.

In short, you can probably blame it on the Python community :P

Comment: How would the grammar be more complicated if the scope of the induction variable were limited to the body of the loop? Such a change would be confined to the semantic analysis in Python, not to its grammar.

Comment: Loops are not blocks in Python.  This sort of behavioral change would call for either changing the grammar fundamentally or providing a special case.  The whole concept of an induction variable is also not expressed in the current grammar.  The grammar provides the contract for how the interpreter will interpret.  My point is that I cannot foresee how a change in this behavior can be done without making the grammar more complicated.  It's all moot since the side effect of the design decision has become a feature.

Comment: This post here https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056677.html
gives more details regarding speed and complication which Mr. Brown alludes to.

Comment: This also helped me considerably with the concept: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/the-scope-of-index-variables-in-pythons-for-loops/

Comment: The solution could be as simple as the `let` keyword in JavaScript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let 
Most languages have a simple mechanism like this because it's clearly a good practice to use and prioritize local scoping when possible.

Answer (score 82):

Python does not have blocks, as do some other languages (such as C/C++ or Java). Therefore, scoping unit in Python is a function.

Comment: I'm confused - what prevents Python from scoping for loops the same way that functions are scoped?

Comment: Not really true, it's just that the grammar doesn't go block-crazy. (http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) "A block is a piece of Python program text that is executed as a unit. The following are blocks: a module, a function body, and a class definition..."

Comment: @thebackhand, nothing. It was just deemed unnecessary.

Comment: @thebackhand - in languages with blocks, scoping `for` loops is a natural extension of a general principle. In Python it would have to be a special case, and special cases are to be avoided unless they have compelling benefits.

Comment: Is it really correct to say Python doesn't have blocks? the indentation rules define blocks

Answer (score 53):

A [really useful case](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/the-scope-of-index-variables-in-pythons-for-loops/) for this is when using `enumerate` and you want the total count in the end:

```
for count, x in enumerate(someiterator, start=1):
    dosomething(count, x)
print "I did something {0} times".format(count)
```

Is this necessary? No. But, it sure is convenient.

Another thing to be aware of: in Python 2, variables in list comprehensions are leaked as well:

```
>>> [x**2 for x in range(10)]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
>>> x
9
```

But, the same does not apply to Python 3.

Comment: You could have done that presumably in the `else` clause, ie. `else: print "I did something {0} times".format(count)` - before local scope (that does not exist in Python) disappears

Comment: Only the second example doesn't work in Python 3, right?  The first still does?  Notes as to why it was removed from Python 3?

Comment: **for count, item in enumerate(a, start=1):**  # default index is from zero

Comment: The first example, rather than being a good use case, seems more like the evidence that this scoping rule is dangerous and should not be relied upon. What if `someiterator` is empty?

Comment: @Nas While an `else` clause could be used in this case, it wouldn't work in general since the loop body could `break` prematurely.

Comment: Meh. There's an off-by-one error in the first example.

Answer (score 5):

One of the primary influences for Python is [ABC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_(programming_language)), a language developed in the Netherlands for teaching programming concepts to beginners. Python's creator, Guido van Rossum, worked on ABC for several years in the 1980s. I know almost nothing about ABC, but as it is intended for beginners, I suppose it must have a limited number of scopes, much like early BASICs.

Answer (score 3):

I might be wrong, but if I am certain that I don't need to access `foo` outside the loop, I would write it in this way

```py
for _foo in xrange(10):
    bar = 2
```

Comment: That's actually quite nice in PyCharm, as it leads to the IDE not showing 'Shadows name xy from outer scope'

Answer (score 1):

If you have a break statement in the loop (and want to use the iteration value later, perhaps to pick back up, index something, or give status), it saves you one line of code and one assignment, so there's a convenience.

Answer (score 1):

It is a design choice in Python, which often makes some tasks easier than in other languages with the typical block scope behavior.

But oftentimes you would still miss the typical block scopes, because, say, you might have large temporary arrays which should be freed as soon as possible. It could be done by temporary function/class tricks but still there is a neater solution achieved with directly manipulating the interpreter state.

```
from scoping import scoping
a = 2 

with scoping():
    assert(2 == a)
    a = 3
    b = 4
    scoping.keep('b')
    assert(3 == a) 

assert(2 == a) 
assert(4 == b)
```

https://github.com/l74d/scoping

Answer (score -8):

For starters, if variables were local to loops, those loops would be useless for most real-world programming.

In the current situation:

```
# Sum the values 0..9
total = 0
for foo in xrange(10):
    total = total + foo
print total
```

yields `45`. Now, consider how assignment works in Python. If loop variables were strictly local:

```
# Sum the values 0..9?
total = 0
for foo in xrange(10):
    # Create a new integer object with value "total + foo" and bind it to a new
    # loop-local variable named "total".
    total = total + foo
print total
```

yields `0`, because `total` inside the loop after the assignment is not the same variable as `total` outside the loop. This would not be optimal or expected behavior.

Comment: Not answering the question. The OP was asking about foo, not total (or bar in their example).

Comment: @JamesBradbury `total` and `foo` would still have loop-local bindings in the OP's scenario and the logic is the same.

Comment: OP: "I can understand why it might be necessary for 'bar' to be accessible outside the loop (otherwise, for loops would have very limited functionality). What I don't understand is why it is necessary for the *control variable* to remain in scope after the loop exits." (emphasis mine)

Comment: @JamesBradbury You might be right, but I answered this three years ago and it's probably not worth debating now.