# Do iteration variable exist after the iteration statement in python?

Tags: python

I have tried this code :

```
for i in range(10)
    print(line, i)

print(line, i)
```

and the program executed without error, so why is `i` declared even after the `for` statement, it must no longer exist.

Comment: have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611760/scoping-in-python-for-loops

Comment: yea sorry didn't saw it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your iteration variable isn’t deleted when the loop is finished. As [the documentation puts it](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement): „Names in the target list are not deleted when the loop is finished”.

This has to do with variable scopes. As has been pointed out, the variable `i` exists within the scope of the function you’re in. A loop does not create an extra scope in python.

Answer (score 0):

The scope is within a function, not a loop.  A little different than other programming languages.