# Python input validation writing to a csv file?

Tags: python, validation, csv, input

I am trying to write user input to a csv file and I want to validate that input. I'm experimenting with the date validation right now I keep receiving the error.
"w.writerow([name, date, employeeid])
NameError: name 'date' is not defined"
and I can't figure out how to fix the error. What's good way to validate raw user input while writing to a csv file so that I don't receive these errors?
Thanks for the help.

Here's my code:

```
import csv
from time import strptime
print "Please fill out the following information:"
with open('userinfo.csv', 'a') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    name = raw_input("Your name:")
    def get_date():
        while True:
            date = raw_input("Please enter a date in MM/DD/YY format:")
            try:
                parsed = strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
            except ValueError as e:
                print "Could not parse date: {0}".format(e)
            else:
                return parsed[:3]
    year, month, day = get_date()

    employeeid =raw_input("EmployeeID:")
    w.writerow([name,date,employeeid])
```

Comment: Don't you actually want `w.writerow([name, year, month, day, employeeid])`? `date` is only defined **inside `get_date`**.

Comment: I want it to write all together in MM/DD/YYYY format but I don't know how I need to define date so that it will actually write to the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`date` was defined in an inner scope (in `get_date()`) and it will be deleted when you exit the `get_date()`, since the interpreter determines that `date` a local variable of `get_date()`.

You need to return `date` from `get_date()` if you want to use it.

**Note**: `date` won't be deleted when exit if it was initially defined in a loop or branch instead of function. See [Jeremy's answer to Python's scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3611987/3199553)

BTW, shouldn't it be `MM/DD/YYYY` format for `strptime`?

Comment: I see where date is defined at but how do I return date from get_date()?

Comment: @just `return parsed[:3], date`. This will return them as a tuple of tuple. And say, do `(year, month, day), _date = get_date()` to receive them.

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding because I made those changes to the two lines and am still receiving the 'date' is not defined error. Can you show me specifically how it will look in my code?

Comment: You need to print `_date` instead of `date` in my example. I just use a different variable name to avoid confusion.

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem. If you still experience any issue, just edit your original post by pasting your full code.

Comment: You were not following my suggestion. See my comments: do a `(year, month, day), _date = get_date()` to receive them.

Comment: And you'd better preserve your old code in your post as well to avoid causing any confusion to other guys who saw this question.

Comment: Could you please show me within my code? I thought that's what I did in line 17. I'm really not understanding what change I'm supposed to make.

Comment: No, your line 17 is `year, month, day = get_date(), _date = get_date()` but what I said is `(year, month, day), _date = get_date()`

Comment: Oh sorry. I confused myself because I made that change in my program but missed it on here. I have the parentheses like that in my actual program and it's still not working.

Comment: Try to `print _date` immediately after line 17 and you should see it printed out correctly. I just gave a try at my local and I am 100% sure that it's right.

Comment: Okay that worked for me. But that's not where I'm having the problem. What's wrong is that is won't write to the CSV file. I get the error "w.writerow([name, date, results]) NameError: name 'date' is not defined.

Comment: Because you need to use `_date` instead of `date`.

Comment: OK, if `_date` caused so much trouble for you, just rename EVERY `_date` variable to `date` in your code, and you should be good.

Comment: The reason that I was using `_date` is to show you the different lifespans of `_date` and `date`, so that you can understand how `date` is deleted and `_date` is present outside of the `get_date()`. If you just want the code to work w/o understanding the details, simply use `date` everywhere. Just forget about `_date`.

Comment: I'm so stupid! I finally got it to work! Thanks so much!