# very wonderous loop behavior: lists changes identity. What is happening?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, scope

Somehow after doing this

```
list2 = [x for x in range(10)]

list1 = [ x for x in range(10,20)]

 for k, list1 in enumerate([list1,list2]):
    for number, entry in enumerate(list1):
        print number, entry
```

suddenly `id(list2)==id(list1)` evaluated to True? What on earth is happening? while the loop is running this does not seem to bee the case the first output is as expected :

0 10, 1 11, 2 12,...0 0, 1 2, 2 3,...

the second though gives:

0 0, 1 1, 2 2...

How is this possible?

Simply changing the code to:

```
list2 = [x for x in range(10)]

list1 = [ x for x in range(10,20)]
```

Gets rid of this behaviour.

```
 for k, NEWVAR in enumerate([list1,list2]):
    for number, entry in enumerate(list1):
        print number, entry
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You write:

```
list1 = [ x for x in range(10,20)]
```

And then:

```
for k, list1 in ...
```

You are using the same name `list1` for two different, but intermixed objects! Nothing good will come out of this.

Just use a different name for the loop:

```
for k, l in enumerate([list1,list2]):
    for number, entry in enumerate(l):
```

Remember that in Python there are only two scopes, roughly speaking:

- module scope and
- function scope.

Answer (score 2):

You are re-assigning `list1` in your for loop:

```
for k, list1 in enumerate([list1,list2]):
```

which means that at the last iteration you're implicitly doing `list1 = list2`

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

> enumerate() returns a tuple containing a count (from start which defaults to 0) and the values obtained from iterating over sequence

Comment: but should the loop not create a new variable in the namescope of the loop?

Comment: @pindakaas: no, the variable is not limited to the for loop scope. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611760/scoping-in-python-for-loops

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop the last value assigned to `list1` ist `list2` and that's why the equality holds true

You are expecting the variables in the for loop to be restricted to the loop but it's not the case. As in:

```
for i in range(0, 2):
    pass

print(i)
```

Which outputs:

```
1
```