# Loop Counting Scoping In Python

Tags: python, scope, palindrome

I'm trying to figure out how this code works. How is `i` accessible outside the for loop?

```
# Palindrome of string
str=raw_input("Enter the string\n")
ln=len(str)
for i in range(ln/2) :
    if(str[ln-i-1]!=str[i]):
        break
if(i==(ln/2)-1):         ## How is i accessible outside the for loop ? 
    print "Palindrome"
else:
    print "Not Palindrome"
```

Comment: for loops do not have their own namespace. [Short Description of Python Scoping Rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules)

Comment: `i` is accessible because loop variables stay in the current scope with their last value unless you assign something else to the name.

Comment: Why? How or what are you implementing this for? It is overly complex for what it does. `mystr == mystr[::-1]`

Comment: Good job actually asking about the specific aspect of the code you don't understand! That makes your question way more answerable.

Comment: Side note: do not use `str` as a variable name, as you are shadowing the built-in [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)

Comment: Also i want understand the logic here , i am not able to get the if condition clearly , suppose my input is (nitin) so can someone guide me how its being evaluated , since the for loop  will be run from i=0 to i = 2

Answer (score 1):

This is part of Python. Variables declared inside for loops (that includes loop counters) won't decay until they fully leave scope.

Take a look at this question:

[Scoping In Python For Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611760/scoping-in-python-for-loops)

From the answers:

> ```
> for foo in xrange(10):
>     bar = 2
> print(foo, bar)
> ```
>
> The above will print (9,2).