# Why does "for num in range(5)" have any effect if num=10 prior to the loop?

Tags: python

I'm given the following program, and I've been asked to write down what it prints:

```
num = 10
for num in range(5):
    print(num)
print(num)
```

My answer is:

`10`

My reasoning is that `num` has been defined to be `10`, so it can't be in the range `(0,5)`, so we can skip this loop. Then, we simply write down what `num` is: 10.

The answer is very different:

```
0
1
2
3
4
4
```

How on earth is this the case, and how could the last line possibly print 4, when `num` has been defined to be `10` at the start?

Comment: `num` in the `for` loop is being assigned whichever number in `range(5)` you are at in the iteration. `num` will be 0,1,2,3,4.

Comment: `for num in range(5)` overwrites the prior value. This isn't Haskell where a name can only be bound to one value.

Comment: You wouldn't skip the loop unless you had some logic like `if num in range(5):`, but you don't. You have `for num in range(5):`. I think you need to read up on your documentation again :)

Comment: @Eugene - Care to explain why you think that?

Comment: @Eugene, ...but I'm not sure that it is. The OP says they don't expect the `for` loop to be run *at all*, not that they don't expect its value to escape the scope after it completes.

Comment: LOL OK I see, OP doesn't quite understand loop variables... or maybe I still don't get it...

Comment: I don't understand the linked answer at all, or all of the other stuff mentioned. If someone could explain where I'm going wrong in the context of really basic Python, that'd be great.

Comment: @SteveSmith - That linked answer has nothing to do with your question. I think Eugene misunderstood.

Comment: @SteveSmith upvoted answer below is correct.

Comment: @SteveSmith, ...so, the short answer is that `for num in range(5)` doesn't care what `num` was before the loop started. Doesn't look at it, doesn't evaluate it, isn't constrained by it, would behave in exactly the same way if the variable didn't exist before the loop was started at all, etc. So, do you know what your code would do if the `i = 10` line didn't exist? That's exactly the same as what it does here.

Comment: @SteveSmith, ...if that answer isn't good enough, we need to know more about your thought process to understand *why* it isn't good enough.

Comment: @SteveSmith would it be helpful if I totally broke it down for you in an answer?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ok, but then why is a `4` printed, at the bottom, rather than a 10? `print(num)` exists outside the `for` loop, so why doesn't it go back to the original value of `num`. Surely, `num` has not been overwritten within the `for` loop.

Comment: @SteveSmith - That is because `num` was last assigned 4 (inside the loop) and you are printing it twice. Once in the loop and once after the loop has exited.

Comment: @SteveSmith, why do you think "surely"? The loop doesn't have its own variable scope, so yes, indeed, it *does* overwrite the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do:

```
for num in range(5):
    print(num)
```

The value you assigned to `num` via `num = 10` is over ridden by the `for` loop. Within the loop, your num is varying from 0 to 4. And when the `for` loop ends, it holds the value as `4`. Outside the loop when you do `print num` it prints `4` because it is holding that last assigned value within `for`.

Comment: And also the fact that list comprehensions also "leak" their loop variable into the surrounding scope. You *should* technically see `10` printed at the end. Ref: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/

Comment: @Eugene This isn't "leak": it's been a part of Python for a long time and loops do not create a new scope. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611760/scoping-in-python-for-loops

Comment: @Eugene: It is actually not a leakage. It is the functionality as in python, loops do not have their own scope which applies to *list comprehension* as well. However, thanks for mentioning it as it might be useful to OP.

Comment: @Eugene Python doesn't really have scopes. All names are bound to their surrounding function, like PHP.

Comment: Got it. Leaking is essentially "non-garbage-collection", which is *not* occurring in this case, and I'm smoking crack thinking that Python has scope. Sorry everyone, it's been 30 hours coding in 5 languages... ah the joys of being a CTO... Apologies again to all, I've made a right Charlie Foxtrot out of this one...

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing up `in` (the boolean operator) with `in` (part of `for` syntax).

The following program is probably what you are thinking of:

```
>>> n = 10
>>> if n in range(5):
...     print(n)
...
>>> print(n)
10
```

In your test program, n loops through the values in `range(5)`, printing those values. It then will print the last assigned value again, hence the repeated 4.

Answer (score 1):

the for loop will change the value of num from 0 to 4, what you are thinking is something like `if num in range(5)` that will ask if num is between (0, 5)

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the for in range loop starts, it overwrites the value of num. So, num starts with the value 10, it enters the for loop, it's value is then set to 0, it prints 0, num is set to 1, prints 1 and so on.

After the for loop, num is printed again, with its new value (the last value of the loop) 4.