# Get count of iterations after for loop is completed

Tags: python, for-loop

In a python for loop, how do I get the value of i below when the loop is completed? Is there any idiomatic way to do that without defining a variable outside and loop and storing `i` within it in each loop run? Like some sort of `finally` for a for loop?

```
for i, data in enumerate(somevar):
    # do something
# get what i was when for loop completed here??
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do nothing. A new scope is not created by your `for` loop. You can access `i` immediately after and outside your loop:

```
for i, data in enumerate(somevar):
    pass

print(i)  # 9
```

See [Scoping in Python 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611760/scoping-in-python-for-loops) for more detail.

Comment: Note: If there is a possibility of the input iterable being empty, add `i = None` or some other marker value before the loop begins (`0` also works, though it can be confused for "exited during the first loop" if you don't change `enumerate`'s `start` value to `1`); otherwise, you risk an `UnboundLocalError` if you try to use `i` when the loop never executed even once.

Comment: this is interesting, loop variable _usually_ never needed outside of the loop. why does python allow this?

Answer (score 2):

`i` will work for what you want.

`for` loops don't have a `finally` block, but they do have an `else` which get's executed if you don't hit a `break` in the main body.

```
for i, value in enumerate(values):
     if value == some_value:
          print("Found the value")
          break
else:
    print("Didn't find value we were looking for")

print("Went through for loop {} times".format(i))
```