# undefined variable does not raise error if in scope of iteration with that name defined

Tags: python, class, dictionary, scope, cpython

Using CPython 3.8.2+ ([984a5](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/984a567cbb2dc4645f2baf72f608d44c9173d190), the following code executes without raising an error.
The result is a dictionary which prints as if it has values that are instances with the same value stored.

```py
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return name  # this is undefined (missing `self.`)


optable = dict()
for name in ['a', 'b']:
    optable[name] = Foo(name)
print(optable)
print(optable['a'].name)
print(optable['b'].name)
```

This script prints

```
{'a': b, 'b': b}
a
b
```

Unexpectedly, both representations are printed, and are "b".

Could this be a CPython bug?

Comment: `name` is pulled from the global scope, it's defined and assigned by the `for` loop.  Try `for item in ['a', 'b']:` instead.

Comment: Additional [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611760/scoping-in-python-for-loops).

Comment: `name` is *not* undefined, Python scoping rules look first at local, then enclosing, and finally global (and built-in) namespace. `name` exists in the global namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, make sure to return the name that belongs to each instance of `Foo`

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```

to prevent returning the global `name` instead.

Also, make sure to use the [correct method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr) to represent the object